# Smallest integer that is not present in the array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

Write a function:

function solution($A);

that, given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A.

For example, given A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], the function should return 5.

For another example, given A = [1, 2, 3], the function should return 4.

Given A = [−1, −3], the function should return 1.

Assume that:

N is an integer within the range [1..100,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [−1,000,000..1,000,000].
Complexity:

expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
expected worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
Elements of input arrays can be modified.

My attempt:

```
function solution($A) {
    $b=min($A);
    $c=max($A);
     for($i=$b; $i<=$c;$i++){
         if($b>0){
                if($b!=1){
                    return 1;
                    }else{
                        for($x=1;$x<=$c;$x++){
                            $b=1;
                            $b=$b+$x;
                            if(!in_array($b,$A)){
                                return $b;
                                }
                        }
                    }
         }else if($b<0 && $c<0){
             return 1;
             }else if($b<0 && $c>0){
                 //was working on this case..
                 }
        //echo $test.'<br>';
    }
}
```

This attempt is 40% correct as per the result.

Comment: are you sure you are looking for smallest positive integer ?

you results are not telling your requirements
please checkout these 

For example, given A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], the function should return 5.

For another example, given A = [1, 2, 3], the function should return 4.

Given A = [−1, −3], the function should return 1.

Comment: for different cases of the array the function must return the smallest possile integer that is not part of that array. @MoeenBasra

Comment: what should be the out put for ['−1', '−3',4,'-5'] ?

Comment: 1 since we are looking for the smallest positive integer and the ans should not be equal to 0. @RavinderReddy

Comment: Start with 1. Is it in the array? Yes->Add 1 and repeat. No->there's your answer.

Comment: For researchers considering techniques on this page... if you have float values in your input array AND you want to use `isset()` on a re-keyed lookup array, then the float values will be truncated to integer values and potentially spoil your result.  @Abra's answer does not suffer from this potential fringe case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not sure what you were trying to do in your code, but just start at 1, check and increment.  The loop will stop as soon as `$i` is not found in the array:

```
function solution($A) {
    for($i=1; in_array($i, $A); $i++);
    return $i;
}
```

Comment: This answer is the cleanest, and correct for real tasks. But given that it's an interview question which contains **expected worst-case time complexity is O(N)**, I wouldn't be surprised if it is rejected. `in_array` is O(N) and the for loop is also O(N); O(N^2) in total. The expected solution could be something like `$tmp=array_flip($A);for($i=1;isset($tmp[$i]);$i++);return $i;`. They can claim that `array_flip` is O(n) (**in reality it isn't**), and that `isset` is O(1) (**in reality it isn't**).

Answer (score 14):

```
function solution($A) {
  $a = array_flip($A);
  for($i=1; isset($a[$i]);$i++);
  return $i;
}
```

Solution with 100% performance score!!

Comment: This is what I would recommend and use, but this answer is missing its educational explanation.  For a question that is seeking algorithmic advice, it is sensible to explain _why_ your answer is best and back up your claim with "science".

Comment: [Look at how this page is bloated by late redundant advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72190356/2943403) purely because you didn't bother to explain your solution.

Answer (score 1):

The prompt does not say the array is ordered, so you can't just increment. You also don't want to do a linear search repeatedly, as the array might be large. Store in something like a hash set (for fast look ups), and skip negative numbers:

PHP implementation:

```
<?php
  function solution(array $arr) {
    $set = [];

    foreach ($arr as $value) {
      if ($value > 0) {
        $set[$value] = $value;
      }
    }

    for ($i = 1; isset($set[$i]); $i++);

    return $i;
  }


  echo solution(array(1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2));//5
  echo solution(array(1, 2, 3));//4
  echo solution(array(-1, -2));//1
?>
```

Comment: Why is `$value` modifiable by reference if you never modify it?  This implementation will not be competing for lowest computational complexity because you make iterated `max()` calls.  Ankit demonstrated the use of `isset()` to leverage the hash map nature of php arrays years earlier and without any `max()` calls.

Comment: First of all, this is the first PHP code I've ever written, and so I might not know all of the details about syntax. Are you talking about the & before $value? Also, what are you talking about with max()? It is comparing two numbers: ```biggest``` and ```value```. It's not iterating anything. What am I missing? The logic of this solution is O(n) in any case.

Comment: With ```max(num1, num2)```, I'm basically trying to do this: ```$biggest = ($biggest < $value) ? $value : $biggest;```. If the latter ternary is more performative than running ```max()``` on two numbers, then I can use the ternary. I don't see how it would be anything but a negligible difference, though. I have in mind ```Math.max(num1, num2)``` in JavaScript. Is ```max(num1, num2)``` in php not doing the same thing?

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that my answer wasn't trying to provide (and the questioner wasn't asking for) a solution "competing for lowest computational complexity", whatever that would mean. It's just an O(n) solution in Javascript. You downvoted because it wasn't in PHP, so I added a PHP solution. And I fail to see why not "competing for lowest computational complexity" merits a downvote. Not every good solution will be maximally low in "computational complexity."

Comment: Somehow I didn't see that there was also a PHP snippet, when I first visited I only noticed the js snippet (maybe while scrolling I thought that the first snippet was part of another answer). Regardless, Ankit's answer demonstrates that making iterated comparisons is not necessary.  Essentially the first loop is not needed. `$biggest` is not necessary. Creating an array of unique values as a lookup array is done with `array_flip()`. The 2nd loop was already posted on the page -- so I cannot lift my DV because I am informing researchers that this answer pales in comparison to upvoted solutions.

Comment: @mickmackusa I have made some minor changes, so please review. Keep in mind that the main point about the new array is that we want it as small as possible, e.g., we want to exclude any numbers that are ```<= 0```. But ```array_flip()``` copies the whole input array. So my solution should not be downvoted because I have an explicit ```foreach``` loop. It's a good loop.

Comment: The conditional filtration of `$set` is an unnecessary overhead BECAUSE you are starting from `1` and using `isset()` in your `for` loop.  This is only going to be slower than the earlier answer because it is literally doing more (unnecessarily).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233950/discussion-between-wesleyac-and-mickmackusa).

Comment: My point is that because `isset()` is O(1) (from what I've read), then it won't matter how big the input array is.  By the nature of array keys being unique, the memory storage of the lookup / hashmap will never be > _n_ and if there are duplicate values it will be < _n_. Running _n_ iterated conditions to _potentially_ reduce the size of the lookup is not beneficial. You could also include a condition to prevent storage if the currently iterated value is greater than the last -- this again is unnecessary workload. This is why I am endorsing `array_flip()`.

Comment: Again, it is O(1), so it won't matter for the purpose of time complexity, BUT MY point was about space complexity. My array will in principle be smaller than copying by default the entire array (which is what ```array_flip()``` does). There's usually a trade off between space and time efficiency. Ankit's is the perhaps slightly more efficient time-wise, and mine is more efficient space-wise. That's what I'm saying. Both are worthy contributions to the discussion and so mine should not be downvoted simply because the first loop is different than his.

Comment: (Please remove comments **if and when** you find them not useful (if for following the discussion) any more.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is function to find the minimum number that do not exist in array.

```
function getMinNotexist($arr) {
    $min = min($arr);
    $max = max($arr);

    if ($min < 0) {
        $min = 0;
    }
    if ($max < 0) {
        $max = 0;
    }

    $upto = $max + 1;

    for ($k = $min; $k <= $upto; $k++) {

        if ($k > 0 and!in_array($k, $arr)) {
            return $k;
        }
    }
}


echo solution(array(1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2)); //return 5
echo solution(array(1, 2, 3)); //return 4 
echo solution(array(-1, -3)); //return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code.

```
// your array 
$array =  [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2];
// define an empty array.
$new_array = array();
// get the max value from your array
$max_number = max($array);
// loop
for($i=1;$i<$max_number;$i++){
    // check for existence in your array  
    if(!in_array($i,$array)){
      // save to new array
      $new_array[]=$i;  
    }
}
echo $small_int = empty($new_array) ? $max_number+1 : min($new_array);
```

Comment: `max_number = max($array) +1` in case the array is [1, 2, 3, 4]

Comment: This answer will not be computationally efficient.  `max()` iterates the whole array.  Calling `in_array()` in a loop is typically not done when efficiency matters.  `!in_array()` also iterates the whole array.

Answer (score 0):

here is what I think

```
$array = [];

for($i=-100; $i<100; $i++) {
    $array[] = rand(-100, 100);
    $i++;
}

$newArray = array_filter($array, function($number) {
    return $number > 0;
});


function getSmallesPositiveNumber($array) {
    for($i=0; $i<=max($array); $i++) {
        if (in_array($i+1, $array)) {
            continue;
        }

        return $i+1;
    }
}

print_r($newArray);
echo getSmallesPositiveNumber($newArray);
```

Comment: Calling `max()` of every iteration is wasteful.  This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy 88%

```
function solution($A) {
    $max = max($A);
     if($max < 0){
        $max = 1;
     }
    $range = range(1,$max+1);
    $diff = array_diff($range,$A);
    $diff = array_values($diff);
    return $diff[0];
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Comment: This snippet is working too hard. `array_diff()` will be iterating and comparing both arrays (needlessly)!  `array_values()` is unnecessay -- just call `reset()` or `current()` on `$diff`.

Answer (score 0):

*This is an upcycled answer from a deleted duplicate post.* As a basic principle, for best performance, we want to avoid any unnecessary and expensive steps. Specifically, *full-array iterations* are heavy. In addition, any functions called at each iteration add to the weight of the operation.

- If you have a large array of integers, `in_array` at each iteration is expensive.
- However, checking `isset` on an array key is a cheap operation.
- Then: use `array_flip` to enable quick index lookups with `isset`.
- No need to filter out negative integers, find unique values, or sort anything.
- No need to compare values as *greater/lesser than* or keep track of anything
- ... just `for` loop from 1 up++ and check matches; first "no-match" is the lowest missing integer.

```
function find_missing_int(array $a) {
    // Get the reference array:
    $int_keys = array_flip($a);
    
    // Loop $i starting from 1 upward:
    for($i = 1; $i <= 1000000; $i++) {
        // If $i doesn't exist in $int_keys, return "solution"
        if(!isset($int_keys[$i])) {
            return $i;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

$int = find_missing_int([1,2,3,...123456789]); // first missing int, or null
```

If this weren't wrapped into a function, you'd want to use `break` in place of `return`, and assign the match to a variable. Reportedly this solution gets a 100% performance score.

*This solution is hard-wired to a maximum of `1000000`.* If you had an arbitrary integer array with potential gaps and no defined upper limit, you *could* run `max($array)`, however that's a *full-array iteration* that would be heavy if you had millions of array members. Since the loop is broken on a match, you could just have `$i < 99999999999999`; however refactoring into a `while` loop would be "cleaner". (Not included here since OP has a defined range maximum.)

P.S. Using `array_flip` to get unique keys is a very useful move for a number of use cases, and cheaper than e.g. `array_unique`. While in this case you'd get the numeric indexes as the values, the values are inconsequential and not used. We only care about looking up the keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
$set = [];

foreach ($arr as $value) {
  if ($value > 0) {
    $set[$value] = $value;
  }
}

for ($i = 1; isset($set[$i]); $i++);

return $i;
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  Why have you posted it? In what way is it superior to previously posted answers?  What value does it add to this page?

Answer (score -1):

As I can see you just need the smallest value of all, if that's the case try this:

```
$cantArray = count($A); // size of the array
$smaller = 0; // Just the position

    for($f = 1; $f < $cantArray; $f++){ 
        if($A[$f] > 0){ 
            if($A[$f] < $A[$smaller]){ 
                $smaller = $f;  
            }
        }
    }


    // At the end just print the smallest
    echo $A[$smaller];
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution
The problem goes like this return the smallest positive integer not in the array and greater than 0$A

Looping through the array I will set the min number to smallest value in the array incase a negative value or value smaller than  1 was given

If yes it will automatically change to 1
Else it will remain the smallest positive number in the array

Then the loop keeps adding 1 to $1

While the loop it check if any $i is in the array

And if not in the array it returns the number

But if the number is greater than the max number in the array it returns
The max number + 1

else it will remain the

```
function solution ($A) {
// written in PHP7.0
for ($i = min ($A); $i <= max($A); $i++) {
if ($i <= 0) {
$i = 1;



}


if(!in_array($i, $A)){

return $i;

}

if($i ==max($A)) {
return $i +1;

}}}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Check out this java code.

```
 public static int solution(int[] a){
    Arrays.sort(a); //O(nlogn)
    int answer = 1; // O(1)
    int positiveCounter = 1; // O(1)
    for (int i = 0; i<=a.length; i++){
        answer = positiveCounter;
        if(i == a.length){
            break;
        }
        if(a[i]<=0){
            continue;
        }
        if(a[i] != positiveCounter){
            break;
        }
        if(i == a.length-1){
            positiveCounter++;
            answer = positiveCounter;
            break;
        }
        if(a[i+1] != positiveCounter){
            positiveCounter++;
        }

    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: This question is clearly tagged as php. Either port this answer to an equivalent java page or ask and self-answer a new question that calls for java solutions.