# Find the smallest positive integer that does not occur in a given sequence

Tags: algorithm

I was trying to solve this problem:

> Write a function:
>
> ```
> class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }
> ```
>
> that, given an array A of N integers, returns the smallest positive
> integer (greater than 0) that does not occur in A.
>
> For example, given A = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], the function should return
> 5.
>
> ```
> Given A = [1, 2, 3], the function should return 4.
>
> Given A = [−1, −3], the function should return 1.
> ```
>
> Assume that:
>
> N is an integer within the range [1..100,000]; each element of array A
> is an integer within the range [−1,000,000..1,000,000]. Complexity:
>
> expected worst-case time complexity is O(N); expected worst-case space
> complexity is O(N) (not counting the storage required for input
> arguments).

I wrote the solution below which gives a low performance, however, I can't see the bug.

```java
public static int solution(int[] A) {

        Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();

        for (int a : A) {
            set.add(a);
        }

        int N = set.size();

        int[] C = new int[N];

        int index = 0;

        for (int a : set) {
            C[index++] = a;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

            if (C[i] > 0 && C[i] <= N) {
                C[i] = 0;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

            if (C[i] != 0) {
                return (i + 1);
            }
        }

        return (N + 1);
    }
```

The score is provided here,

[image]

I will keep investigating myself, but please inform me if you can see better.

Comment: I can write better solution, but get puzzled on this

Comment: @ruakh `Collections.sort()` and his solution works

Comment: @ruakh You're right :-)   ... but maybe this belongs on Code Review since it's already running...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen With a correctness of 20%, it absolutely does not belong on Code Review. The speed is irrelevant as long as it simply doesn't work.

Comment: @Arefe I don't see the result of the score. Are you still able to see it now?

Comment: @Pingpong I haven't use Codility for a while, but, you should be able to see it after the completion of the test unless they have changed the format.

Comment: @Arefe I don't see it now, I am not using a registered user account, not sure if it has something to do with it.

Comment: The original question is asked for Java, but other programmers started to provide many answers that I didn't expect. So, I just remove the Java tag now.

Comment: In your question: _expected worst-case time complexity is O(N)_. But in
[a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51719848#comment114567070_64797692)
you ask for a 100% score in the
[codility demo test](https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test/)?
Some answers here sort the array as
part of their solution, implying O(N log(N)) rather than O(N), but
still report that their solution scores 100% in the codility test.
Could you clarify which is more important – the
desire to score 100% on the test – or that the algorithm may perform
no worse than O(N), asymptotically?

Comment: this question is [discussed at meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418024/839601)

Answer (score 158, accepted):

If the expected running time should be linear, you can't use a `TreeSet`, which sorts the input and therefore requires `O(NlogN)`. Therefore you should use a `HashSet`, which requires `O(N)` time to add `N` elements.

Besides, you don't need 4 loops. It's sufficient to add all the positive input elements to a `HashSet` (first loop) and then find the first positive integer not in that Set (second loop).

```
int N = A.length;
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
for (int a : A) {
    if (a > 0) {
        set.add(a);
    }
}
for (int i = 1; i <= N + 1; i++) {
    if (!set.contains(i)) {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you find the first positive integer not in the set in n time? n is the size of the input, not the maximum possible integer of the problem.

Comment: @Jorge.V since N is the size of the input, the first positive integer not in the input is at most N+1 (if the input array contains all the numbers between 1 and N). Therefore the second loop will run at most N+1 iterations. Hence O(N).

Comment: @Eran you could set the size of your hash set, not that it makes much of a difference, but it would prevent the possibility of having to search inside of each bin.

Comment: @matt I guess you can set the initial capacity to N to save the need to resize the backing HashMap, but on the other hand, it would be wasteful if most of the input numbers are negative (and therefore not added to the Set).

Comment: such an easy and understandable solution :)

Comment: Add this couple of lines so it returns when the array is like this [-1,-3]

`int N = A.length, res = 1;
     boolean found = false;
     Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
     for (int a : A) {
         if (a > 0) {
             set.add(a);
         }
     }
     for (int i = 1; i <= N + 1 && !found; i++) {
         if (!set.contains(i)) {
             res = i;
             found = true;
         }
     }
        return res;`

Comment: This solution is trivial and Codility gonna complain about performance result. AFAIK, the problem is not about the complexity but the memory usage. The complexity is O(n) but the memory is N too which is too big. Must have some elegant solutions

Comment: How can this be O(n)?? It seems to me like O(nlog(n)) because of the "contains" method in the second loop.

Comment: @sotn if you use HashSet, contains takes O(1) expected time.

Comment: Yeap, totally :) Thanks.

Comment: `if (!set.contains(i))`
OR
    `if (!set.contains(A[i]))`
?

Answer (score 90):

100% result solution in Javascript:

```
function solution(A) {
    // only positive values, sorted
    A = A.filter(x => x >= 1).sort((a, b) => a - b)

    let x = 1

    for(let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        // if we find a smaller number no need to continue, cause the array is sorted
        if(x < A[i]) {
            return x
        }
        x = A[i] + 1
    }

    return x
}
```

Comment: Looks like they changed the tests: chaotic sequences length=10005 (with minus) got 2 expected 101. I think the question on the site is not well written...

Comment: ```
function solution(A) {
    return Array.from(new Set(A.filter((a)=>a=>1))).sort((a,b)=>a-b).reduce((prev,n,i)=>{
       if (n===prev) return n+1
       else return prev
    },1)
}
```

Comment: This gets 100% score. (just run it out of curiosity.

Comment: As of August 2021 this solution passes 100% of all the sets of test cases in codility website.

Answer (score 60):

My code in Java, 100% result in Codility

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] arr) {
        Arrays.sort(arr);

        int smallest = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == smallest) {
                smallest++;
            }
        }
        return smallest;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: A perfect Solution

Comment: `Arrays.sort(arr);` is O(N log(N) ), while O(N) solution is expected.

Comment: You don't need those checks. It will work with just sort and that for loop.

Comment: agree with @Aivean, in the other hand runtime complexity here  O(N log(N) ), but you not use extra space, so space complexity is O(1)

Comment: well, all these solutions will alter the array... so i would not consider them correct.

Answer (score 26):

Here is an efficient python solution:

```
def solution(A):
    m = max(A)
    if m < 1:
       return 1

    A = set(A)
    B = set(range(1, m + 1))
    D = B - A
    if len(D) == 0:
        return m + 1
    else:
        return min(D)
```

Comment: I think the test case [-10,-3] breaks your solution. You will return -2 when you should return 1.

Comment: @YagoCaruso `if m < 1:` takes care of it.

Comment: The line `A = set(A)` is interesting. If you don't reuse the identifier `A` when creating the set, you will get 88% score instead of 100%. (Meaning one of the performance tests fail.) Apparently, Python can work faster by reusing the array when creating the set? Any comments on that?

Comment: why is this more efficient than doing `A = set(A)` and then looping over a `range(1, 100_001)` and checking if the element is `in A`? set(A) is O(n) and the loop is O(m), with n being the size of the array (could be 2 million) and m between 1 and 100K. I only got a 75% score for this solution and wonder why

Comment: This is not efficient at all. You iterate the set once just to get the max(A); then you iterate it again to get the `set(A)`; then you create a new set with `range`, and you iterate `A` again to find the differences in the two sets. This is at least `O(3N)`, whilst this problem can be resolved in `O(N)`.

Comment: In big-O notation O(3n)=O(n)! In addition in python usually using build-in functions is faster and more optimized than looping though. Please provide your solution/code and tested in the platform for the benefit of all.

Answer (score 24):

JS:

- `filter` to get positive non zero numbers from A array
- `sort` above filtered array in ascending order
- `map` to iterate loop of above stored result

  - `if` to check `x` is less than the current element then return
  - otherwise, add 1 in the current element and assign to `x`

```js
function solution(A) {

    let x = 1
    
    A.filter(x => x >= 1)
     .sort((a, b) => a - b)
     .map((val, i, arr) => {
        if(x < arr[i]) return
        x = arr[i] + 1
    })

    return x
}

console.log(solution([3, 4, -1, 1]));
console.log(solution([1, 2, 0]));
```

Comment: While this might be an answer, but it needs explanations and details to be written.

Comment: Why would you give a JavaScript answer to a question tagged with [tag:java]?

Comment: This gets 100% score. (just run it out of curiosity.

Comment: `filter` is used just so the original array is not mutated.

Comment: _Why would you give a JavaScript answer to a question tagged with java?_
The tag [tag:java] has since been removed.

Comment: to use map you dont need the 3 params, only val will work fine.

Comment: .map((val) => x < val ? x : x = val + 1);

Answer (score 17):

No need to store anything. No need for hashsets. (Extra memory), You can do it as you
move through the array. However, The array has to be sorted. And we know the very most minimum value is 1

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        Arrays.sort(A);     
        int min = 1; 
        /*
         for efficiency — no need to calculate or access the 
         array object’s length property per iteration 
        */
        int cap = A.length; 

        
        for (int i = 0; i < cap; i++){
            if(A[i] == min){
                min++;
            }
        /* 
           can add else if A[i] > min, break; 
           as suggested by punit
         */
        }   
        /*
          min = ( min <= 0 ) ? 1:min; 
          which means: if (min <= 0 ){
          min =1} else {min = min} 
          you can also do: 
          if min <1 for better efficiency/less jumps
         */
        return min;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Your time complexity is `O(N*log(N))` so it violates the question requirement of `...expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);...`

Comment: In if condition, can't we put
if(A.indexOf(A[i] + 1) < 0){
           return min;
}

Comment: why? explain why you think so. & indexOf is used on Lists so you'd have to convert the array to a list or use an arraylist to start with .. that is if you badly want to use indexOf. .. knowing that 1 is the most minimum, you wouldn't check against 0 maybe < 1 or < 2.. what do you think ?.. so if any number +1 is < 0 would be logically challenging as a solution .. if you also happen to return at that point, then you haven't checked the entire array for the smallest value.. you've just checked until your condition was met.

Comment: you should add else condition that if A[i] > min then break the loop. Since you have already sorted the array, you don't have to iterate till the end.

Comment: I would think that the Java compiler would optimize the for(;;) statement to fetch A.length once, knowing that A does not change in the loop.

Answer (score 13):

Here is my PHP solution, 100% Task Score, 100% correctness, and 100% performance. First we iterate and we store all positive elements, then we check if they exist,

```
function solution($A) {

    $B = [];
    foreach($A as $a){ 
        if($a > 0) $B[] = $a;   
    }

    $i = 1;
    $last = 0;
    sort($B);

    foreach($B as $b){

        if($last == $b) $i--; // Check for repeated elements
        else if($i != $b) return $i;

        $i++;
        $last = $b;        

    }

    return $i;
}
```

I think its one of the clears and simples functions here, the logic can be applied in all the other languages.

Comment: I can confirm that the total score at https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test is 100%. (I.e. both correctness and performance are 100%.)

Comment: I didn't understand this example.

Comment: Simpler PHP approach with 100% efficiency: [Smallest integer that is not present in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48822210/2943403) ...and it was posted one year before this answer.

Answer (score 13):

I achieved 100% on this by the below solution in Python:-

```
def solution(A):
   a=frozenset(sorted(A))
   m=max(a)
   if m>0:
       for i in range(1,m):
           if i not in a:
              return i
       else:
          return m+1
   else:
       return 1
```

Answer (score 13):

For Swift 4

```
public func solution(_ A : inout [Int]) -> Int {
  let positive = A.filter { $0 > 0 }.sorted()
  var x = 1
  for val in positive {
  // if we find a smaller number no need to continue, cause the array is sorted
    if(x < val) {
      return x
    }
    x = val + 1
  }
  return x
}
```

Comment: Nah, fails for redundant elements. It won't work for e.g. [4, 1, 2, 2].

Answer (score 9):

This solution is in c# but complete the test with 100% score

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    // write your code in C# 6.0 with .NET 4.5 (Mono)
    var positives = A.Where(x => x > 0).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
    if(positives.Count() == 0) return 1;
    int prev = 0;
    for(int i =0; i < positives.Count(); i++){

        if(positives[i] != prev + 1){
            return prev + 1;
        }
         prev = positives[i];
    }
    return positives.Last() + 1;
}
```

Comment: Good to see other languages around

Answer (score 9):

My answer in Ruby

```rb
def smallest_pos_integer(arr)
  sorted_array = arr.select {|x| x >= 1}.sort
  res = 1

  for i in (0..sorted_array.length - 1)
    if res < sorted_array[i]
      return res
    end
    res = sorted_array[i] + 1
  end
  res
end
```

Answer (score 8):

In Kotlin with %100 score
Detected time complexity: O(N) or O(N * log(N))

```kotlin
fun solution(A: IntArray): Int {
    var min = 1
    val b = A.sortedArray()
    for (i in 0 until b.size) {
        if (b[i] == min) {
            min++
        }
    }
    return min
}
```

Comment: Very clever, below is the C# version of it.

Array.Sort(A);
            int min = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
            {
                if (A[i] == min)
                    min++;
            }
            return min;

Comment: I like this answer as it is both simple and elegant. Correctness = 5 out of 5. Performance = 4 out of 4. https://app.codility.com/c/feedback/demoD2HV3D-535/ I noticed that if I use `sorted` instead of `sortedArray`, then it fails on only one of the performance tests. Very nice! https://app.codility.com/c/feedback/demoGHDCFT-EZ4/

Answer (score 7):

This answer gives 100% in Python. Worst case complexity O(N).

The idea is that we do not care about negative numbers in the sequence, since we want to find the smallest positive integer not in the sequence A.
Hence we can set all negative numbers to zero and keep only the unique positive values. Then we check iteratively starting from 1 whether the number is in the set of positive values of sequence A.

Worst case scenario, where the sequence is an arithmetic progression with constant difference 1,  leads to iterating through all elements  and thus O(N) complexity.

In the extreme case where all the elements of the sequence are negative (i.e. the maximum is negative) we can immediately return 1 as the minimum positive number.

```py
def solution(A):
    max_A=max(A)
    B=set([a if a>=0 else 0 for a in A ])
    b=1
    if max_A<=0:
        return(1)
    else:
        while b in B:
            b+=1
        return(b)
```

Comment: I know it has been a while but do you think you could add some comments to this to explain what is happening?

Comment: @JamesG. Edited my answer above and added the intuition behind it. Hope it provides more clarity.

Comment: little improvement:
B =  set([a for a in x if a >= 0])
* we don't need zero values after all

Answer (score 7):

Javascript solution:

```
function solution(A) {
    A = [...new Set(A.sort( (a,b) => a-b))];

    // If the initial integer is greater than 1 or the last integer is less than 1
    if((A[0] > 1) || (A[A.length - 1] < 1)) return 1;

    for (let i in A) {
        let nextNum = A[+i+1];
        if(A[i] === nextNum) continue;
        if((nextNum - A[i]) !== 1) {
            if(A[i] < 0 ) {
                if(A.indexOf(1) !== -1) continue;
                return 1;
            }
            return A[i] + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem in all possible scenarios - performance and logic.

Answer (score 6):

My solution in JavaScript, using the reduce() method

```js
function solution(A) {
  // the smallest positive integer = 1
  if (!A.includes(1)) return 1;

  // greater than 1
  return A.reduce((accumulator, current) => {
    if (current <= 0) return accumulator
    const min = current + 1
    return !A.includes(min) && accumulator > min ? min : accumulator;
  }, 1000000)
}

console.log(solution([1, 2, 3])) // 4
console.log(solution([5, 3, 2, 1, -1])) // 4
console.log(solution([-1, -3])) // 1
console.log(solution([2, 3, 4])) // 1
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/the-smallest-positive-integer-zu4s2

Comment: This score 66% on the website.

Comment: @lesyk Yeah. Not passed on the performance tests with large sequences. The message that occurred is "Timeout error. Killed. Hard limit reached 6 seconds". Does someone have a solution for that?

Answer (score 6):

100% solution in Swift, I found it [here](https://github.com/chebur/Codility/blob/master/Codility.playground/Pages/MissingInteger.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift), it is really beautiful than my algo... No need to turn array as ordered, instead using dictionary `[Int: Bool]` and just check the positive item in dictionary.

```swift
public func solution(_ A : inout [Int]) -> Int {
    var counter = [Int: Bool]()
    for i in A {
        counter[i] = true
    }

    var i = 1
    while true {
        if counter[i] == nil {
            return i
        } else {
            i += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Best one I have seen so far

Answer (score 6):

I figured an easy way to do this was to use a `BitSet`.

- just add all the positive numbers to the BitSet.
- when finished, return the index of the first clear bit after bit 0.

```java
public static int find(int[] arr) {
    BitSet b = new BitSet();
    for (int i : arr) {
        if (i > 0) {
            b.set(i);
        }
    }
    return b.nextClearBit(1);
}
```

Comment: This is interesting. Does it work 100% score in the Codility? Especially, we need to check it for negative numbers.

Comment: The negative numbers are ignored since I am only using positive numbers to set the bit positions (the requirement was to find the first positive number).  I don't have access to Codility.  If you do feel free to check it out.  But I would be interested in the results.  I did check it out on some very large data sets.  Worst case was using 1 to 100,000,000 in the array.  It came back with 100,000,001 in about 1 second.

Comment: I just ran this on Codility.  It received 100% on everything.  Worse case test took .28 seconds.

Comment: This one is good. However you need to add another clause to your condition, specifically, `if (i > 0 && i <= arr.length)`. This will ensure `O(N)` upper space and time bound. Without this clause, if your your space and time bound is O( K ), where `K` is maximal value of `arr`.

Answer (score 6):

**JavaScript ES6 Solution:**

```js
function solution(A) {
  if (!A.includes(1)) return 1;
  return A.filter(a => a > 0)
    .sort((a, b) => a - b)
    .reduce((p, c) => c === p ? c + 1 : p, 1);
}
console.log(solution([1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2]));
console.log(solution([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(solution([-1, -3]));
console.log(solution([4, 5, 6]));
console.log(solution([1, 2, 4]));
```

Comment: Short and elegant. And it scores 100% at https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test. 
(A little more explanation could make it easier to understand the code, notably the `.reduce` line.)

Answer (score 6):

#### 0. Introduction

##### A) Languages allowed

[The Codility skills assessment demo test](https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test) allows for solutions
written in 18 different languages: `C, C++, C#, Go, Java 8, Java 11, JavaScript, Kotlin, Lua, Objective-C, Pascal, PHP, Perl, Python, Ruby, Scala, Swift 4, Visual Basic`.

##### B) Some remarks on your question

> I write the solution below which gives a low performance

There is no reason to worry about performance until you have a
*correct* solution.
Always make sure the solution is *correct* before you even think about
how fast or slow your algorithm/code is!

> expected worst-case time complexity is O(N)

Well, as the asker of the question, it is your decision what
requirements should be met in an answer.
But if the goal is to score 100% in the Codility (performance) test,
then there is no need to demand O(N).
There are plenty of solutions in the answers here which are O(N log N)
and *not* O(N), but still pass all 4 performance tests.
This proves that the O(N) requirement on time complexity is
unnecessarily harsh (if the sole aim is to score 100% on the Codility
test).

##### C) About the solutions presented here

All of the solutions presented here are either refactored versions of
already published answers, or inspired by such answers.
*All solutions here score 100%* in [the Codility skills assessment
demo test](https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test).
<sup>1</sup>

I have striven to

- explicitly reference each original answer/solution,
- provide a runnable [jdoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com) link for each
  solution,
- use the same 8 tests (chosen by myself) for all the solutions,
- choose solutions that score 100% (meaning 5 of 5 for correctness and
  4 of 4 for performance/speed),
- make it easy to copy-paste the answers directly into [the Codility
  skills assessment demo test](https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test),
- focus on some of *the most used languages*.

#### 1. Java: the Codility test for correctness is incorrect (!)

I will use [one of the existing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57067307) to demonstrate that the Codility
test for correctness is flawed for the edge case when the given array
is empty.
In an empty array, the smallest positive missing integer is clearly 1.
Agreed?

But the Codility test suite seems to accept just about *any* answer for
the empty array.
In the code below, I deliberately return `-99` for the empty array,
which is obviously incorrect.
Yet, Codility gives me a 100% test score for my flawed solution. (!)

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test 100%
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57067307
https://jdoodle.com/a/3B0D
To run the program in a terminal window:
  javac Solution.java && java Solution && rm Solution.class
Terminal command to run the combined formatter/linter:
  java -jar ../../../checkstyle-8.45.1.jar -c ../../../google_checks.xml *.java
*/
public class Solution {
  /** Returns the smallest positive integer missing in intArray. */
  public static int solution(int[] intArray) {
    if (intArray.length == 0) { // No elements at all.
      return -99; // So the smallest positive missing integer is 1.
    }
    Arrays.sort(intArray);
    // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray)); // Temporarily uncomment?
    if (intArray[0] >= 2) { // Smallest positive int is 2 or larger.
      return 1; // Meaning smallest positive MISSING int is 1.
    }
    if (intArray[intArray.length - 1] <= 0) { // Biggest int is 0 or smaller.
      return 1; // Again, smallest positive missing int is 1.
    }
    int smallestPositiveMissing = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
      if (intArray[i] == smallestPositiveMissing) {
        smallestPositiveMissing++;
      } // ^^ Stop incrementing if intArray[i] > smallestPositiveMissing. ^^
    }   // Because then the smallest positive missing integer has been found:
    return smallestPositiveMissing;
  }

  /** Demo examples. --> Expected output: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 (but vertically). */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello Codility Demo Test for Java, B");
    int[] array1 = {-1, -3};
    System.out.println(solution(array1));
    int[] array2 = {1, -1};
    System.out.println(solution(array2));
    int[] array3 = {2, 1, 2, 5};
    System.out.println(solution(array3));
    int[] array4 = {3, 1, -2, 2};
    System.out.println(solution(array4));
    int[] array5 = {};
    System.out.println(solution(array5));
    int[] array6 = {1, -5, -3};
    System.out.println(solution(array6));
    int[] array7 = {1, 2, 4, 5};
    System.out.println(solution(array7));
    int[] array8 = {17, 2};
    System.out.println(solution(array8));
  }
}
```

Below is a screen dump of the result from the test.
As the solution is clearly wrong, of course it should not score 100%!
<sup>2</sup>

[image: The Codility test scores 100% for an ERRONEOUS solution!]

#### 2. JavaScript

Below is a JavaScript solution.
This one has *not* been posted before, but is inspired by
[one of the previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61658386).

```js
/**
https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test 100%
(c) Henke 2022 https://stackoverflow.com/users/9213345
https://jdoodle.com/a/3AZG
To run the program in a terminal window:
  node CodilityDemoJS3.js
Terminal command to run the combined formatter/linter:
  standard CodilityDemoJS3.js
https://github.com/standard/standard
*/
function solution (A) {
/// Returns the smallest positive integer missing in the array A.
  let smallestMissing = 1
  // In the following .reduce(), the only interest is in `smallestMissing`.
  // I arbitrarily return '-9' because I don't care about the return value.
  A.filter(x => x > 0).sort((a, b) => a - b).reduce((accumulator, item) => {
    if (smallestMissing < item) return -9 // Found before end of the array.
    smallestMissing = item + 1
    return -9 // Found at the end of the array.
  }, 1)
  return smallestMissing
}
// Demo examples. --> Expected output: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 (but vertically).
// Note! The following lines need to be left out when running the
// Codility Demo Test at https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test :
console.log('Hello Codility Demo Test for JavaScript, 3.')
console.log(solution([-1, -3]))
console.log(solution([1, -1]))
console.log(solution([2, 1, 2, 5]))
console.log(solution([3, 1, -2, 2]))
console.log(solution([]))
console.log(solution([1, -5, -3]))
console.log(solution([1, 2, 4, 5]))
console.log(solution([17, 2]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### 3. Python

Python has come to compete with Java as one of the most used
programming languages worldwide.
The code below is a slightly rewritten version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58980724).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
'''
https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test 100%
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58980724
https://jdoodle.com/a/3B0k
To run the program in a terminal window:
    python codility_demo_python_a.py
Command in the terminal window to run the linter:
    py -m pylint codility_demo_python_a.py
https://pypi.org/project/pylint/
Dito for autopep8 formatting:
    autopep8 codility_demo_python_a.py --in-place
https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/
'''


def solution(int_array):
    '''
    Returns the smallest positive integer missing in int_array.
    '''
    max_elem = max(int_array, default=0)
    if max_elem < 1:
        return 1
    int_array = set(int_array)  # Reusing int_array although now a set
    # print(int_array)  # <- Temporarily uncomment at line beginning
    all_ints = set(range(1, max_elem + 1))
    diff_set = all_ints - int_array
    if len(diff_set) == 0:
        return max_elem + 1
    return min(diff_set)


# Demo examples. --> Expected output: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 (but vertically).
# Note! The following lines need to be commented out when running the
# Codility Demo Test at https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test :
print('Hello Codility Demo Test for Python3, a.')
print(solution([-1, -3]))
print(solution([1, -1]))
print(solution([2, 1, 2, 5]))
print(solution([3, 1, -2, 2]))
print(solution([]))
print(solution([1, -5, -3]))
print(solution([1, 2, 4, 5]))
print(solution([17, 2]))
```

#### 4. C#

Here a solution for C#, inspired by [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56031565).

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
/// https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test 100%
/// (c) 2021 Henke, https://stackoverflow.com/users/9213345
/// https://jdoodle.com/a/3B0Z
/// To initialize the program in a terminal window, only ONCE:
///   dotnet new console -o codilityDemoC#-2 && cd codilityDemoC#-2
/// To run the program in a terminal window:
///   dotnet run && rm -rf obj && rm -rf bin
/// Terminal command to run 'dotnet-format':
///   dotnet-format --include DemoC#_2.cs && rm -rf obj && rm -rf bin
public class Solution {
  /// Returns the smallest positive integer missing in intArray.
  public int solution(int[] intArray) {
    var sortedSet =
      intArray.Where(x => x > 0).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
    // Console.WriteLine("[" + string.Join(",", sortedSet) + "]"); // Uncomment?
    if (sortedSet.Length == 0) return 1; // The set is empty.
    int smallestMissing = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedSet.Length; i++) {
      if (smallestMissing < sortedSet[i]) break; // The answer has been found.
      smallestMissing = sortedSet[i] + 1;
    } // Coming here means all of `sortedSet` had to be traversed.
    return smallestMissing;
  }

  /// Demo examples. --> Expected output: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 (but vertically).
  /// NOTE! The code below must be removed before running the Codility test.
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello Codility Demo Test for C#, 2.");
    int[] array1 = { -1, -3 };
    Console.WriteLine((new Solution()).solution(array1));
    int[] array2 = { 1, -1 };
    Console.WriteLine((new Solution()).solution(array2));
    int[] array3 = { 2, 1, 2, 5 };
    Console.WriteLine((new Solution()).solution(array3));
    int[] array4 = { 3, 1, -2, 2 };
    Console.WriteLine((new Solution()).solution(array4));
    int[] array5 = { };
    Console.WriteLine((new Solution()).solution(array5));
    int[] array6 = { 1, -5, -3 };
    Console.WriteLine((new Solution()).solution(array6));
    int[] array7 = { 1, 2, 4, 5 };
    Console.WriteLine((new Solution()).solution(array7));
    int[] array8 = { 17, 2 };
    Console.WriteLine((new Solution()).solution(array8));
  }
}
```

#### 5. Swift

Here is a solution for Swift, taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57063839).

```swift
/**
https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test 100%
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57063839
https://www.jdoodle.com/a/4ny5
*/
public func solution(_ A : inout [Int]) -> Int {
/// Returns the smallest positive integer missing in the array A.
  let positiveSortedInts = A.filter { $0 > 0 }.sorted()
// print(positiveSortedInts) // <- Temporarily uncomment at line beginning
  var smallestMissingPositiveInt = 1
  for elem in positiveSortedInts{
  // if(elem > smallestMissingPositiveInt) then the answer has been found!
    if(elem > smallestMissingPositiveInt) { return smallestMissingPositiveInt }
    smallestMissingPositiveInt = elem + 1
  }
  return smallestMissingPositiveInt // This is if the whole array was traversed.
}
// Demo examples. --> Expected output: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 (but vertically).
// Note! The following lines need to be left out when running the
// Codility Demo Test at https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test :
print("Hello Codility Demo Test for Swift 4, A.")
var array1 = [-1, -3]
print(solution(&array1))
var array2 = [1, -1]
print(solution(&array2))
var array3 = [2, 1, 2, 5]
print(solution(&array3))
var array4 = [3, 1, -2, 2]
print(solution(&array4))
var array5 = [] as [Int]
print(solution(&array5))
var array6 = [1, -5, -3]
print(solution(&array6))
var array7 = [1, 2, 4, 5]
print(solution(&array7))
var array8 = [17, 2]
print(solution(&array8))
```

#### 6. PHP

Here a solution for PHP, taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60535808).

```php
<?php
/**
https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test 100%
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60535808
https://www.jdoodle.com/a/4nB0
*/
function solution($A) {
  $smallestMissingPositiveInt = 1;
  sort($A);
  foreach($A as $elem){
    if($elem <=0) continue;
    if($smallestMissingPositiveInt < $elem) return $smallestMissingPositiveInt;
    else $smallestMissingPositiveInt = $elem + 1; 
  }
  return $smallestMissingPositiveInt;
}
// Demo examples. --> Expected output: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 .
// Note! The starting and ending PHP tags are needed when running
// the code from the command line in a *.php file, but they and
// the following lines need to be left out when running the Codility
// Demo Test at https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test :
echo "Hello Codility Demo Test for PHP, 1.\n";
echo solution([-1, -3]) . " ";
echo solution([1, -1]) . " ";
echo solution([2, 1, 2, 5]) . " ";
echo solution([3, 1, -2, 2]) . " ";
echo solution([]) . " ";
echo solution([1, -5, -3]) . " ";
echo solution([1, 2, 4, 5]) . " ";
echo solution([17, 2]) . " ";
?>
```

#### References

- [The Codility skills assessment demo test](https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test)
- [The LeetCode playground](https://leetcode.com/playground/)
- [A correct Java solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57067307)
- [A correct JavaScript solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61658386)
- [A correct Python 3 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58980724)
- [A correct C# solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56031565)
- [A correct Swift 4 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57063839)
- [A correct PHP solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60535808)

---

<sup>1</sup>
This is true even for the first solution – the Java solution –
*despite the the fact that this solution is **wrong***!

<sup>2</sup> You can try running the test yourself at
https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test.
You will have to sign up to do so.
Simply copy-paste all of the code from the snippet.
The default is `Java 8`, so you won't need to change the language
for the first solution.

Comment: clever solution

Comment: Can you print out the score percentage for the PHP solution

Comment: All 6 solutions score 100%, including the PHP solution.
I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: There are plenty of good solutions among the answers here.
I've chosen to include only _one_ solution per language.
So I'm more inclined to add more of _other languages_ than adding more solutions of languages that I've already included.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple and fast code in **PHP**.

- **Task Score:**  100%
- **Correctness:** 100%
- **Performance:** 100%
- **Detected time complexity:** O(N) or O(N * log(N))

```php
function solution($A) {
    
    $x = 1;
    
    sort($A);
    
    foreach($A as $i){
        
        if($i <=0) continue;
        
        if($x < $i) return $x;
        
        else $x = $i+1; 
        
    }
    
    return $x;
}
```

[Performance tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGT1n.png)

Comment: Amazing! Concise and well performing but it blows the brains.
I'w suggest not to change the original array, sort the copy.

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript solution without sort, 100% score and O(N) runtime. It builds a hash set of the positive numbers while finding the max number.

```
function solution(A) {
    set = new Set()
    let max = 0
    for (let i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
        if (A[i] > 0) {
            set.add(A[i])
            max = Math.max(max, A[i])
        }
    }

    for (let i=1; i<max; i++) {
        if (!set.has(i)) {
            return i
        }
    }
    return max+1
}
```

Comment: fantastic approach

Answer (score 4):

My solution having 100% result in codility with Swift 4.

```
func solution(_ A : [Int]) -> Int {
    let positive = A.filter { $0 > 0 }.sorted()
    var x = 1
    for val in positive{
        if(x < val) {
            return x
        }
        x = val + 1
    }
    return x
}
```

Comment: What is original in this answer? What purpose is special casing `1`? Why let `index` assume values up to `result.count - 1` just to exclude the upper bound with an extra `if`?

Comment: special casing `1` is for if that array doesn't contain 1 that means 1 is the result which is the smallest integer not available in array.

And index is assumed upto `result.count - 1` just because inner condition checks for `index + 1` where it will get fail with index out of bound. So we have to check only upto last index. And if the for loop finish upto last index and we don't found the smallest integer then last return line will return the next integer after the last element.

You can copy this solution to codility to check the output and result.

Comment: @greybeard If this solution helped you then give up vote plz.

Comment: This is uncommented code in a language the question is not tagged with. It contains code for a special case that does "not" change the result without giving a motivation (avoiding a superlinear processing step comes to mind). It uses an extra conditional statement to fix an inapt choice of loop limit. It uses four comparisons per iteration where one would suffice. Not only does this solution not help me: It annoys me.

Comment: (Was about to add blame for `A : inout` (***why* out**?), but that has to go to [codility.com](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/4-counting_elements/missing_integer/).)

Comment: @greybeard Please check the updated solution. I hope that help you.

Comment: Can we do it with reduce rather than for loop?

Comment: @EmreÖnder Yes I think possible using reduce as well.

Answer (score 4):

My simple and (time) efficient Java solution:

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        Set<Integer> set=new TreeSet<>();
        for (int x:A) {
            if (x>0) {
                set.add(x);
            }
        }

        int y=1;
        Iterator<Integer> it=set.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            int curr=it.next();
            if (curr!=y) {
                return y;
            }
            y++;
        }
        return y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First let me explain about the algorithm down below.
If the array contains no elements then return 1,
Then in a loop check if the current element of the array is larger then the previous element by 2 then there is the first smallest missing integer, return it.
If the current element is consecutive to the previous element then the current smallest missing integer is the current integer + 1.

```
    Array.sort(A);

    if(A.Length == 0) return 1;

    int last = (A[0] < 1) ? 0 : A[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
    {
        if(A[i] > 0){
            if (A[i] - last > 1) return last + 1;
            else last = A[i];
        } 
    }

    return last + 1;
```

Comment: I tried this, three of the corner cases were missing. I modified this by adding an additional statemen of "if(A[0]>1) return 1; all the corner cases got covered and gave a 100% on all three

Answer (score 4):

This my implementation in Swift 4 with 100% Score. It should be a pretty similar code in Java. Let me know what you think.

```
public func solution(_ A : inout [Int]) -> Int {
  let B = A.filter({ element in
    element > 0
  }).sorted()

  var result = 1
  for element in B {
    if element == result {
      result = result + 1
    } else if element > result {
      break
    }
  }

  return result
}
```

[image: Codility Test Result]

Answer (score 4):

This is the solution in C#:

```cs
using System;
// you can also use other imports, for example:
using System.Collections.Generic;

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// Console.WriteLine("this is a debug message");

class Solution {
public int solution(int[] A) {
    // write your code in C# 6.0 with .NET 4.5 (Mono)
int N = A.Length;
HashSet<int> set =new HashSet<int>();
foreach (int a in A) {
if (a > 0) {
    set.Add(a);
    }
}
for (int i = 1; i <= N + 1; i++) {
if (!set.Contains(i)) {
    return i;
    }
}
return N;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is for C#, it uses HashSet and Linq queries and has 100% score on Codility

```
     public int solution(int[] A)
    {
        var val = new HashSet<int>(A).Where(x => x >= 1).OrderBy((y) =>y).ToArray();
        var minval = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < val.Length; i++)
        {
            if (minval < val[i])
            {
                return minval;
            }
            minval = val[i] + 1;
        }

        return minval;
    }
```

Comment: So does return Enumerable.Range(1, 100001).Except(A).First();

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea solution is short and conscience.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing too much. You've create a TreeSet which is an order set of integers, then you've tried to turn that back into an array. Instead go through the list, and skip all negative values, then once you find positive values start counting the index. If the index is greater than the number, then the set has skipped a positive value.

```
int index = 1;
for(int a: set){
    if(a>0){
        if(a>index){
            return index;
        } else{
            index++;
        }
    }
}
return index;
```

Updated for negative values.

A different solution that is O(n) would be to use an array. This is like the hash solution.

```
int N = A.length;
int[] hashed = new int[N];

for( int i: A){
    if(i>0 && i<=N){
        hashed[i-1] = 1;
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
    if(hash[i]==0){
        return i+1;
    }
}
return N+1;
```

This could be further optimized counting down the upper limit for the second loop.

Comment: `expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);` - adding N elements to a TreeSet requires `O(NlogN)` time.

Comment: @Eran I thought the first concern was getting it correct. I don't know an O(N) solution offhand.

Comment: Does your code work for this set[]={1,4} .I think you will not get the min positive integer.

Comment: @Nivedh The first method I wrote would return 2 in that case. I updated it because it was broken for negative numbers. I also added an O(n) version.

Comment: @matt The second solution is impressive. I'd use a `boolean[]` to express the intent that this is a flag, and rename it from `hash` to or `appeared`. And you can have N = A.length + 1, which will make the other code slightly simpler and easier to understand, as it can become `appeared[i]`, and `if (!appeared[i]) return i;`.

Answer (score 3):

For the space complexity of `O(1)` and time complexity of `O(N)` and if the array can be modified then it could be as follows:

```
public int getFirstSmallestPositiveNumber(int[] arr) {
    // set positions of non-positive or out of range elements as free (use 0 as marker)
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] <= 0 || arr[i] > arr.length) {
            arr[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    //iterate through the whole array again mapping elements [1,n] to positions [0, n-1]
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int prev = arr[i];
        // while elements are not on their correct positions keep putting them there
        while (prev > 0 && arr[prev - 1] != prev) {
            int next = arr[prev - 1];
            arr[prev - 1] = prev;
            prev = next;
        }
    }

    // now, the first unmapped position is the smallest element
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != i + 1) {
            return i + 1;
        }
    }
    return arr.length + 1;
}

@Test
public void testGetFirstSmallestPositiveNumber() {
    int[][] arrays = new int[][]{{1,-1,-5,-3,3,4,2,8},
      {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, 
      {0, 3, -2, -1, 1}};

    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(getFirstSmallestPositiveNumber(arrays[i]));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> 5
>
> 6
>
> 2

Comment: @Arefe sorry, I didn't get how another solution would work. For example, how will it work for a `{3, 2, 1}`  array?

Comment: @Arefe Sure, but I didn't get the exact steps that the algorithm will do to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

I find another solution to do it with additional storage,

```
/*
* if A = [-1,2] the solution works fine
* */
public static int solution(int[] A) {

    int N = A.length;

    int[] C = new int[N];

    /*
     * Mark A[i] as visited by making A[A[i] - 1] negative
     * */
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        /*
         * we need the absolute value for the duplicates
         * */
        int j = Math.abs(A[i]) - 1;

        if (j >= 0 && j < N && A[j] > 0) {
            C[j] = -A[j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        if (C[i] == 0) {
            return i + 1;
        }
    }

    return N + 1;
}
```

Comment: With your algorithm, a sample test like `{-1, 2}` will return `2` instead of `1`.  The problem is that `0` position is occupied by the negative value (`-1`) and your `if (A[i] > 0) ` check will return `false` for it.

Comment: ok cant do it O(1) space, needed storage. The answer is updated

Comment: Actually, you can do it without using additional storages if the negatives are set to 0 earlier ie you have done in your example.

Comment: No storage is needed for this. And no need to tamper with the original array by setting anything to 0 Take a look at my solution

Answer (score 3):

```
//My recursive solution:

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        return next(1, A);
    }
    public int next(int b, int[] A) {
        for (int a : A){
            if (b==a)
                return next(++b, A);
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some text explaining why your answer works

Comment: It's good you tried and find a recursive solution I was not aware of. However, it requires a sorting in the primary method before can start the recursion and hence, can't be solved with `O(N)`. Have a great day.

Comment: It can be done by recursion without sorting:

https://pastebin.com/yERsyKzV

Comment: The solution does not finish in O(n) time. e.g. [n, n-1, n-2, ....., 2, 1] will provide the worst performane O(n^2)

Comment: The solution is correct but it's performance-intensive and won't pass in the Codility

Answer (score 3):

```
<JAVA> Try this code-

private int solution(int[] A) {//Our original array

        int m = Arrays.stream(A).max().getAsInt(); //Storing maximum value
        if (m < 1) // In case all values in our array are negative
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (A.length == 1) {

            //If it contains only one element
            if (A[0] == 1) {
                return 2;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        int i = 0;
        int[] l = new int[m];
        for (i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            if (A[i] > 0) {
                if (l[A[i] - 1] != 1) //Changing the value status at the index of our list
                {
                    l[A[i] - 1] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < l.length; i++) //Encountering first 0, i.e, the element with least value
        {
            if (l[i] == 0) {
                return i + 1;
            }
        }
        //In case all values are filled between 1 and m
        return i+1;
    }
Input: {1,-1,0} , o/p: 2
Input: {1,2,5,4,6}, o/p: 3
Input: {-1,0,-2}, o/p: 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution in C++. It got a 100% score (100% correctness, 100% performance) (after multiple tries ;)). It relies on the simple principle of comparing its values to their corresponding index (after a little preprocessing such as sorting). I agree that your solution is doing too much; You don't need four loops.

The steps of my solution are basically:

1. Sort and remove any duplicates. There are two possible methods here, the first one utilizing `std::sort`, `std::unique`, and `erase`, while the second one takes advantage of `std::set` and the fact that a set sorts itself and disallows duplicates
2. Handle edge cases, of which there are quite a few (I missed these initially, causing my score to be quite low at first). The three edge cases are:

   - All ints in the original array were negative
   - All ints in the original array were positive and greater than 1
   - The original array had only 1 element in it
3. For every element, check if its value != its index+1. The first element for which this is true is where the smallest missing positive integer is. I.e. if `vec.at(i) != i+1`, then `vec.at(i-1)+1` is the smallest missing positive integer.
4. If `vec.at(i) != i+1` is false for all elements in the array, then there are no "gaps" in the array's sequence, and the smallest positive int is simply vec.back()+1 (the 4th edge case if you will).

And the code:

```
int solution(vector<int>& rawVec)
{
    //Sort and remove duplicates: Method 1
    std::sort(rawVec.begin(), rawVec.end());
    rawVec.erase(std::unique(rawVec.begin(), rawVec.end()), rawVec.end());

    //Sort and remove duplicates: Method 2
    // std::set<int> s(rawVec.begin(), rawVec.end());
    // rawVec.assign(s.begin(), s.end());

    //Remove all ints < 1
    vector<int> vec;
    vec.reserve(rawVec.size());
    for(const auto& el : rawVec)
    {
        if(el>0)
            vec.push_back(el);
    }

    //Edge case: All ints were < 1 or all ints were > 1
    if(vec.size()==0 or vec.at(0) != 1)
        return 1;

    //Edge case: vector contains only one element
    if(vec.size()==1)
        return (vec.at(0)!=1 ? 1 : 2);

    for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(vec.at(i) != i+1)
            return vec.at(i-1)+1;
    }
    return vec.back()+1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This code has been writen in Java SE 8

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {        

        int smallestPositiveInt = 1; 

        if(A.length == 0) {
            return smallestPositiveInt;
        }

        Arrays.sort(A);

        if(A[0] > 1) {
            return smallestPositiveInt;
        }

        if(A[A.length - 1] <= 0 ) {
            return smallestPositiveInt;
        }

        for(int x = 0; x < A.length; x++) {
            if(A[x] == smallestPositiveInt) { 
                smallestPositiveInt++;
             }    
        }

        return smallestPositiveInt;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorting the array is O (N log N) - which is larger than the O(N) budget

Comment: Nice solution, you can make it even simpler if you remove check for whether array is of size 0, as task states that minimum size is 1: "N is an integer within the range [1..100,000]; "

Answer (score 3):

```
public static int solution(int[] A) {
    Arrays.sort(A);
    int minNumber = 1;
    int length = A.length - 1;
    int max = A[length];
    Set < Integer > set = new HashSet < > ();
    for (int i: A) {
        if (i > 0) {
            set.add(i);
        }
    }
    for (int j = 1; j <= max + 1; j++) {
        if (!set.contains(j)) {
            minNumber = j;
            break;
        }
    }
    return minNumber;
}
```

Comment: sorting the array is O (N log N) - which is larger than the O(N) budget

Answer (score 3):

This solution runs in O(N) complexity and all the corner cases are covered.

```
   public int solution(int[] A) {
        Arrays.sort(A);
        //find the first positive integer
        int i = 0, len = A.length;
        while (i < len && A[i++] < 1) ;
        --i;

        //Check if minimum value 1 is present
        if (A[i] != 1)
            return 1;

        //Find the missing element
        int j = 1;
        while (i < len - 1) {
            if (j == A[i + 1]) i++;
            else if (++j != A[i + 1])
                return j;
        }

        // If we have reached the end of array, then increment out value
        if (j == A[len - 1])
            j++;
        return j;
    }
```

Comment: `This solution runs in O(N) complexity` sure? What `Arrays.sort()` do you use/assume? (Try and benchmark, say, one million "random" integers, 7, 49, 243 million.)

Comment: `Arrays.sort()` will take O(N log N) time complexity. So time complexity of this application will be O(N log N), assuming that constants are ignored.

Comment: My take of above code, too: compare to other answers and consider editing your post.

Answer (score 3):

Solution in Scala with all test cases running:

```
Class Solution {

  def smallestNumber(arrayOfNumbers: Array[Int]) = {
    val filteredSet = arrayOfNumbers.foldLeft(HashSet.empty[Int]){(acc, next) 
    => if(next > 0) acc.+(next) else acc}
    getSmallestNumber(filteredSet)

  }

  @tailrec
  private def getSmallestNumber(setOfNumbers: HashSet[Int], index: Int = 1): 
  Int = {
      setOfNumbers match {
        case emptySet if(emptySet.isEmpty) => index
        case set => if(!set.contains(index)) index else getSmallestNumber(set, 
          index + 1)
        }
      }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The code below is is simpler but my motive was to write for JavaScript, ES6 users:

```
function solution(A) {
   
    let s = A.sort();
    let max = s[s.length-1];
    let r = 1;
   
    // here if we have an array with [1,2,3] it should print 4 for us so I added max + 2
    for(let i=1; i <= (max + 2); i++) {
        r  = A.includes(i) ? 1 : i ;
        if(r>1) break;
    }
   
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My python solution 100% correctness

```
def solution(A):

  if max(A) < 1:
    return 1

  if len(A) == 1 and A[0] != 1:
    return 1

  s = set()
  for a in A:
    if a > 0:
      s.add(a)
  
  
  for i in range(1, len(A)):
    if i not in s:
      return i

  return len(s) + 1

assert solution([1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2]) == 5
assert solution([1, 2, 3]) == 4
assert solution([-1, -3]) == 1
assert solution([-3,1,2]) == 3
assert solution([1000]) == 1
```

Answer (score 3):

With 100% Accuracy on codility in Java

```
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8

     Arrays.sort(A);
    int i=1;
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < A.length; i1++) {
      if (A[i1] > 0 && i < A[i1]) {
        return i;
      }else if(A[i1]==i){
         ++i;
      }

    }
    return i;
    }
```

Comment: performance will degrade in event of large arrays

Answer (score 3):

My Javascript solution. This got 100%. The solution is to sort the array and compare the adjacent elements of the array.

```
function solution(A) {
// write your code in JavaScript (Node.js 8.9.4)
  A.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  if (A[0] > 1 || A[A.length - 1] < 0 || A.length === 2) return 1;

  for (let i = 1; i < A.length - 1; ++i) {
    if (A[i] > 0 && (A[i + 1] - A[i]) > 1) {
        return A[i] + 1;
    }
  }

  return A[A.length - 1] + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

this is my code in Kotlin:

```
private fun soluction(A: IntArray): Int {
   val N = A.size
   val counter = IntArray(N + 1)

   for (i in A)
       if (i in 1..N)
           counter[i]++
   
   for (i in 1 until N + 1)
       if (counter[i] == 0)
           return i
     
   return N + 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

100% in Swift using recursive function. O(N) or O(N * log(N))

```
var promise = 1

public func solution(_ A : inout [Int]) -> Int {
    // write your code in Swift 4.2.1 (Linux)
    execute(A.sorted(), pos: 0)
    return promise

}

func execute(_ n:[Int], pos i:Int) {
    if n.count == i || n.count == 0 { return }
    if promise > 0 && n[i] > 0 && n[i]+1 < promise {
        promise = n[i] + 1
    } else if promise == n[i] {
        promise = n[i] + 1
    }
    execute(n, pos: i+1)
}
```

Comment: This should be the top answer! The only one that scored 100% on Codility

Answer (score 3):

In C# you can write simple below code.

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
      int maxSize = 100000;
        int[] counter = new int[maxSize];

        foreach (var number in A)
        {
            if(number >0 && number <= maxSize)
            {
                counter[number - 1] = 1;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++)
        {
            if (counter[i] == 0)
                return i + 1;
        }


        return maxSize + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I used Python. First I sorted, then filtered corner cases, then removed elements <1. Now element and index are comparable.

```
def solution(A):
    A = sorted(set(A))
    if A[0]>1 or A[-1]<=0:
        return 1
    x = 0
    while x<len(A):
        if A[x]<=0:
            A.pop(x)
            x-=1
        x+=1
    for i, x in enumerate(A):
        if not x==i+1:
            return i+1
    return i+2
```

Codility finds it okay..
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Go language : Find the smallest positive integer that does not occur in a given sequence

> GO language:
>
> - sort above given array in ascending order
> - map to iterate loop of above stored result, if to check x is less than the current element then return, otherwise, add 1 in the current element and assign to x

```
package main
    
import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func Solution(nums []int) int {
    sort.Ints(nums)
    x := 1
    for _, val := range nums {
        if(x < val) {
            return x
        }
        if(val >= 0) {
            x = val + 1
        }
    }
    return x
}

func main() {

    a1 := []int{1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2}
    fmt.Println(Solution(a1))    // Should return : 5

    a2 := []int{1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Println(Solution(a2))    // Should return : 4

    a3 := []int{-1, -3}
    fmt.Println(Solution(a3))    // Should return : 1

    a4 := []int{4, 5, 6}
    fmt.Println(Solution(a4))    // Should return : 1

    a5 := []int{1, 2, 4}
    fmt.Println(Solution(a5))    // Should return : 3

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function solution(A) {
    const mylist = new Set(A);
    for(i=1;i<= mylist.size+1;i++){
       if(!mylist.has(i)) {
           return i;
       }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Late joining the conversation. Based on:

```
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/179091/184415
```

There is indeed an O(n) complexity solution to this problem even if duplicate ints are involved in the input:

```
solution(A)
Filter out non-positive values from A
For each int in filtered
    Let a zero-based index be the absolute value of the int - 1
    If the filtered range can be accessed by that index  and  filtered[index] is not negative
        Make the value in filtered[index] negative

For each index in filtered
    if filtered[index] is positive
        return the index + 1 (to one-based)

If none of the elements in filtered is positive
    return the length of filtered + 1 (to one-based)

So an array A = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6], would have the following transformations:

abs(A[0]) = 1, to_0idx = 0, A[0] = 1, make_negative(A[0]), A = [-1,  2,  3,  5,  6]
abs(A[1]) = 2, to_0idx = 1, A[1] = 2, make_negative(A[1]), A = [-1, -2,  3,  5,  6]
abs(A[2]) = 3, to_0idx = 2, A[2] = 3, make_negative(A[2]), A = [-1, -2, -3,  5,  6]
abs(A[3]) = 5, to_0idx = 4, A[4] = 6, make_negative(A[4]), A = [-1, -2, -3,  5, -6]
abs(A[4]) = 6, to_0idx = 5, A[5] is inaccessible,          A = [-1, -2, -3,  5, -6]

A linear search for the first positive value returns an index of 3. Converting back to a one-based index results in solution(A)=3+1=4
```

Here's an implementation of the suggested algorithm in C# (should be trivial to convert it over to Java lingo - cut me some slack common):

```
public int solution(int[] A)
{
    var positivesOnlySet = A
        .Where(x => x > 0)
        .ToArray();

    if (!positivesOnlySet.Any())
        return 1;

    var totalCount = positivesOnlySet.Length;
    for (var i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) //O(n) complexity
    {
        var abs = Math.Abs(positivesOnlySet[i]) - 1;
        if (abs < totalCount && positivesOnlySet[abs] > 0) //notice the greater than zero check 
            positivesOnlySet[abs] = -positivesOnlySet[abs];
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < totalCount; i++) //O(n) complexity
    {
        if (positivesOnlySet[i] > 0)
            return i + 1;
    }

    return totalCount + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that using structures such as: sets or dicts to store unique values is not the better solution, because you end either looking for an element inside a loop which leads to O(N*N) complexity or using another loop to verify the missing value which leaves you with O(N) linear complexity but spending more time than just 1 loop.

Neither using a counter array structure is optimal regarding storage space because you end up allocating MaxValue blocks of memory even when your array only has one item.

So I think the best solution uses just one for-loop, avoiding structures and also implementing conditions to stop iteration when it is not needed anymore:

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
    // write your code in Java SE 8
    int len = A.length;
    int min=1;
    
    Arrays.sort(A);

    if(A[len-1]>0)
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        if(A[i]>0){
            if(A[i]==min) min=min+1;
            if(A[i]>min) break;
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

This way you will get complexity of O(N) or O(N * log(N)), so in the best case you are under O(N) complexity, when your array is already sorted

Comment: Java SE 8's Arrays.sort is O(n log(n)) as per https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-int:A-, so how can this have a best case of O(N)?

Answer (score 2):

```
package Consumer;


import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class codility {
public static void main(String a[])
    {
        int[] A = {1,9,8,7,6,4,2,3};
        int B[]= {-7,-5,-9};
        int C[] ={1,-2,3};
        int D[] ={1,2,3};
        int E[] = {-1};
        int F[] = {0};
        int G[] = {-1000000};
        System.out.println(getSmall(F));
    }
    public static int getSmall(int[] A)
    {
        int j=0;
        if(A.length < 1 || A.length > 100000) return -1;
        List<Integer> intList = Arrays.stream(A).boxed().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
         if(intList.get(0) < -1000000 || intList.get(intList.size()-1) > 1000000) return -1;
         if(intList.get(intList.size()-1) < 0) return 1;
        int count=0;         
         for(int i=1; i<=intList.size();i++)
         {
             if(!intList.contains(i))return i;
             count++;
         }
         if(count==intList.size()) return ++count;
        return -1;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Answers [should consist of](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) more than a mere code-dump. If you think the question is poorly asked, you can flag it or post a comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public int solution(int[] A) {

    int res = 0;
    HashSet<Integer> list = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i : A) list.add(i);
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++) {
        if(!list.contains(i)){
            res = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Python implementation of the solution. Get the set of the array - This ensures we have unique elements only. Then keep checking until the value is not present in the set - Print the next value as output and return it.

```
def solution(A):
# write your code in Python 3.6
    a = set(A)
    i = 1
    while True:
        if i in A:
            i+=1
        else:
            return i
    return i
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Works 100%. tested with all the condition as described.

```
//MissingInteger
    public int missingIntegerSolution(int[] A) {
        Arrays.sort(A);
        long sum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<=A[A.length-1]; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }


        Set<Integer> mySet = Arrays.stream(A).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
        Integer[] B = mySet.toArray(new Integer[0]);
        if(sum < 0)
            return 1;

        for(int i=0; i<B.length; i++) {
            sum -= B[i];
        }

        if(sum == 0) 
            return A[A.length-1] + 1;
        else
            return Integer.parseInt(""+sum);
    }

int[] j = {1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2,5};

System.out.println("Missing Integer : "+obj.missingIntegerSolution(j));
```

Output Missing Integer : 7

```
int[] j = {1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2};
System.out.println("Missing Integer : "+obj.missingIntegerSolution(j));
```

Output Missing Integer : 5

Answer (score 2):

For JavaScript i would do it this way:

```js
function solution(arr)
{
    let minValue = 1;

    arr.sort();

    if (arr[arr.length - 1] > 0)
    {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] === minValue)
            {
                minValue = minValue + 1;
            }
            if (arr[i] > minValue)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return minValue;
}
```

Tested it with the following sample data:

```
console.log(solution([1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2]));
console.log(solution([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(solution([-1, -3]));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Love to see the JavaScript here.

Comment: (@U2m: `Love to see the JavaScript here` as an answer to a question you tagged [tag:java]? How come?)

Comment: @greybeard I commented because its primarily an algo question.

Comment: I've seen that there were php and python answers as well, so i was thinking maybe someone looking for javascript one :)))

Comment: Not a big fan of JavaScript, but, I see it's fine here ;)

Comment: I just tried this in a codility practice test and it wasn't impressed with the performance passing 0 out of 4 performance tests!

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
  public int solution(int[] A) {
        int N = A.length;
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (int a : A) {
            if (a > 0) {
                set.add(a);
            }
        }
        for (int index = 1; index <= N; index++) {
            if (!set.contains(index)) {
                return index;
            }
        }
        return N + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In C#, bur need improvement.

```
    public int solution(int[] A) {
          int retorno = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
            {
                int ultimovalor = A[i] + 1;
                if (!A.Contains(ultimovalor))
                {
                    retorno = (ultimovalor);
                    if (retorno <= 0) retorno = 1;
                }
            }
            return retorno;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// you can also use imports, for example:
// import java.util.*;

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// System.out.println("this is a debug message");

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
    int size=A.length;
    int min=A[0];
    for(int i=1;i<=size;i++){
        boolean found=false;
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
            if(A[j]<min){min=A[j];}
            if(i==A[j]){
                found=true;
            }
        }
            if(found==false){
                return i;

            }
        }

    if(min<0){return 1;}
        return size+1;



    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

100% result solution in Javascript:

```
function solution(A) {
 let N,i=1;
    A = [...new Set(A)]; // remove duplicated numbers form the Array
    A = A.filter(x => x >= 1).sort((a, b) => a - b); //  remove negative numbers & sort array
    while(!N){ // do not stop untel N get a value
      if(A[i-1] != i){N=i} 
      i++;
    }
    return N;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code in python with comments to understand the code -
[Codility 100% Missing Integer](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingD4VU29-XZH/)

Code-

```
def solution(A):
"""
solution at https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingV4KX2W-3KS/
100%
idea is to take temp array of max length of array items
for all positive use item of array as index and mark in tem array as 1 ie. present item
traverse again temp array if first found value in tem array is zero that index is the smallest positive integer
:param A:
:return:
"""
max_value = max(A)
if max_value < 1:
    # max is less than 1 ie. 1 is the smallest positive integer
    return 1
if len(A) == 1:
    # one element with 1 value
    if A[0] == 1:
        return 2
    # one element other than 1 value
    return 1
# take array of length max value
# this will work as set ie. using original array value as index for this array
temp_max_len_array = [0] * max_value
for i in range(len(A)):
    # do only for positive items
    if A[i] > 0:
        # check at index for the value in A
        if temp_max_len_array[A[i] - 1] != 1:
            # set that as 1
            temp_max_len_array[A[i] - 1] = 1
print(temp_max_len_array)
for i in range(len(temp_max_len_array)):
    # first zero ie. this index is the smallest positive integer
    if temp_max_len_array[i] == 0:
        return i + 1
# if no value found between 1 to max then last value should be smallest one
return i + 2


 arr = [2, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2]    
 result = solution(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution. First we start with 1, we loop over the array and compare with 2 elements from the array, if it matches one of the element we increment by 1 and start the process all over again.

```
private static int findSmallest(int max, int[] A) {

    if (A == null || A.length == 0)
        return max;

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (i == A.length - 1) {
            if (max != A[i])
                return max;
            else
                return max + 1;
        } else if (!checkIfUnique(max, A[i], A[i + 1]))
            return findSmallest(max + 1, A);
    }
    return max;
}


private static boolean checkIfUnique(int number, int n1, int n2) {
    return number != n1 && number != n2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution written in ruby simple  correct and efficient

```rb
def solution(arr)

  sorted = arr.uniq.sort
  last = sorted.last
  return 1 unless last > 0

  i = 1
  sorted.each do |num|
    next unless num > 0
    return i unless num == i

    i += 1
  end
  i

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my JavaScript solution which scored 100% with O(N) or O(N * log(N)) detected time complexity:

```js
function solution(A) {
    let tmpArr = new Array(1);

    for (const currNum of A) {
        if (currNum > arr.length) {
            tmpArr.length = currNum;
        }
        tmpArr[currNum - 1] = true;
    }

    return (tmpArr.findIndex((element) => element === undefined) + 1) || (tmpArr.length + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Java Solution** - 
**Inside de method solution**

```java
int N = A.length;

Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
for (int a : A) {
    if (a > 0) {
        set.add(a);
    }
}

if(set.size()==0) {
    return N=1;
}

for (int i = 1; i <= N + 1; i++) {
    if (!set.contains(i)) {
        N= i;
        break;
    }
}
return N;
```

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C example:

```
 int solution(NSMutableArray *array) {
     NSArray* sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
     int x = 1;
     for (NSNumber *number in sortedArray) {

       if (number.intValue < 0) {
         continue;
       }
       if (x < number.intValue){
         return x;
       }
      x = number.intValue + 1;
     }

     return x;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function solution(A = []) {
    return (A && A
        .filter(num => num > 0)
        .sort((a, b) => a - b)
        .reduce((acc, curr, idx, arr) => 
            !arr.includes(acc + 1) ? acc : curr, 0)
        ) + 1;
}
```

solution(); // 1
solution(null); // 1
solution([]); // 1
solution([0, 0, 0]); // 1

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

```js
// Codility Interview Question Solved Using Javascript

const newArray = []; //used in comparison to array with which the solution is required

const solution = (number) => {
  //function with array parameter 'number'
  const largest = number.reduce((num1, num2) => {
    return num1 > num2
      ? num1
      : num2; /*finds the largest number in the array to
                                   be used as benchmark for the new array to
                                   be created*/
  });

  const range = 1 + largest;
  for (
    let x = 1;
    x <= range;
    x++ //loop to populate new array with positive integers
  ) {
    if (x > range) {
      break;
    }
    newArray.push(x);
  }
  console.log("This is the number array: [" + number + "]"); //array passed
  console.log("This is the new array: [" + newArray + "]"); //array formed in relation to array passed
  const newerArray = newArray.filter((elements) => {
    //array formed frome unique values of 'newArray'
    return number.indexOf(elements) == -1;
  });
  console.log(
    "These are numbers not present in the number array: " + newerArray
  );

  const lowestInteger = newerArray.reduce((first, second) => {
    //newerArray reduced to its lowest possible element by finding the least element in the array
    return first < second ? first : second;
  });
  console.log("The lowest positive integer is " + lowestInteger);
};
solution([1, 2, 3, 4, 6]); //solution function to find the lowest possible integer invoked
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.

Answer (score 2):

The code below will run in O(N) time and O(N) space complexity. Check this [codility](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/demoYBZRMP-S5E/) link for complete running report.

The program first put all the values inside a HashMap meanwhile finding the max number in the array. The reason for doing this is to have only unique values in provided array and later check them in constant time. After this, another loop will run until the max found number and will return the first integer that is not present in the array.

```
   static int solution(int[] A) {
      int max = -1;
      HashMap<Integer, Boolean> dict = new HashMap<>();
      for(int a : A) {
         if(dict.get(a) == null) {
            dict.put(a, Boolean.TRUE);
         }
         if(max<a) {
            max = a;
         }
      }
      for(int i = 1; i<max; i++) {
         if(dict.get(i) == null) {
            return i;
         }
      }
      return max>0 ? max+1 : 1;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution is in Javascript but complete the test with 100% score and less codes

```
function solution(A) {
    let s = A.sort((a, b) => { return a - b })
    let x = s.find(o => !s.includes(o+1) && o>0)
    return ((x<0) || !s.includes(1)) ? 1 : x+1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in C#

```
static int solutionA(int[] A)
    {
        Array.Sort(A);

        int minNumber = 1;

        if(A.Max() < 0)
        {
            return minNumber;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            if (A[i] == minNumber)
            {
                minNumber++;
            }
            
            if (A[i] > minNumber)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return minNumber;
    }
```

[100% Test Pass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1exBE.png) https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvPR8.png

Answer (score 2):

**Swift** version using functions rather than an iterative approach

'The solution obtained perfect score' - Codility
[image]

This solution uses functions rather than an iterative approach. So the solution relies heavily on the language's optimizations. A similar approach could be done in **Java** such as using Java's set operations and other functions.

```
public func solution(_ A : inout [Int]) -> Int {
    let positives = A.filter{ $0 > 0}
    let max = positives.count <= 100_000 ? positives.count + 1 : 100_001
    return Set(1...max).subtracting(A).min() ?? -1
}
```

1. Obtained all positive numbers from the source array.
2. Obtained all possible results based on the positive count. Limited the set to 100k as stated in the problem. Added 1 in case the source array was a complete sequence.
3. Returned the minimum positive number after excluding the source array's
   elements from the set of all possible results.

*Note: The function declaration was from Codility and inout was unneeded. Returning an integer did not allow for nil so -1 was used.*

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the accepted answer with Swift. `Hashset` in Swift is `Set`. I think if index is required as return value then try to use `Dictionary` instead.

Passed with 100% score.

```
public func solution(_ A: [Int]) -> Int {
    let n = A.count
    var aSet = Set<Int>()
    
    for a in A {
        if a > 0 {
            aSet.insert(a)
        }
    }
    
    for i in 1...n+1 {
        if !aSet.contains(i) {
            return i
        }
    }
    
    return 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The below C++ solution obtained a 100% score. The theoretical complexity of the code is. Time Complexity : O(N) amortized due to hash set and Auxiliary Space complexity of O(N) due to use of hash for lookup in O(1) time.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<climits>
#include<cmath>
#include<unordered_set>

using namespace std;

int solution(vector<int>& A)
{
  if(!A.size())
    return(1);

  unordered_set<int> hashSet;
  int maxItem=INT_MIN;
  for(const auto& item : A)
  {
    hashSet.insert(item);
    if(maxItem<item)
      maxItem=item;
  }

  if(maxItem<1)
    return(1);

  for(int i=1;i<=maxItem;++i)
  {
    if(hashSet.find(i)==hashSet.end())
      return(i);
  }
  return(maxItem+1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use this, which is a variant of Insertion-Sort, without the need of Set, or sorting the whole array.

```
    public static int solution(int[] A) {
    //we can choose only positive integers to enhance performance
        A = Arrays.stream(A).filter(i -> i > 0).toArray();
        for(int i=1; i<A.length; i++){
            int v1 = A[i];
            int j = i-1;
            while (j > -1 && A[j] > v1) {
                A[j + 1] = A[j];
                j = j - 1;
            }
            A[j + 1] = v1;
            if(A[i] - A[i-1] > 1){
                return A[i] + 1;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Without sorting or extra memory.
Time Complexity: O(N)

```
  public int firstMissingPositive(int[] A) {
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            if (A[i] < 1 || A[i] > A.length)
                continue;
            
            int val = A[i];
            while (A[val-1] != val) {
                int t = A[val-1];
                A[val-1] = val;
                val = t;
                if (val < 1 || val > A.length)
                    break;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
            if (A[i] != i + 1)
                return i + 1;
        
        return A.length + 1;
    }
```

Comment: you are right corrected

Comment: Quite similar to [Anatolii's 2018 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51720330).

Answer (score 2):

Below is my solution

```
int[] A = {1,2,3};
Arrays.sort(A);
Set<Integer> positiveSet = new HashSet<>();
for(int a: A) {
    if(a>0) {
        positiveSet.add(a);
    }
}
for(int a: A) {
    int res = a+1;
    if(!positiveSet.contains(res)) {
        System.out.println("result : "+res);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking about another approach (JS, JavaScript) and got this results that score 66% because of performance issues:

```
    const properSet = A.filter((item) => { return item > 0 });
    let biggestOutsideOfArray = Math.max(...properSet);
    
    if (biggestOutsideOfArray === -Infinity) {
       biggestOutsideOfArray = 1;
    } else {
        biggestOutsideOfArray += 1;
    }
    
   for (let i = 1; i <= biggestOutsideOfArray; i++) {
       if(properSet.includes(i) === false) {
           return i;
       }
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about just playing around with loops.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class SmallestPositiveNumber {

    public int solution(int[] A) {
        Arrays.sort(A);
        int SPI = 1;

        if(A.length <= 1) return SPI;

        for(int i=0; i<A.length-1; i++){

            if((A[i+1] - A[i]) > 1)
            {
                return A[i] + 1;
            }
        }
        return A[A.length-1]+1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution on Java:

```
public int solution(int[] A) {

   int smallestPositiveInteger = 1;
        
   Arrays.sort(A);

   if(A[0] <= 0) return smallestPositiveInteger;

      for( int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
          if(A[i] == smallestPositiveInteger)
            smallestPositiveInteger++;
      }    

      return smallestPositiveInteger;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Shortest answer in Python. 100%

```
def solution(A):
   return min([x for x in range(1,len(A) + 2) if x not in set(sorted([x for x in A if x>0 ]))])
```

Comment: I ran this at https://app.codility.com/demo/take-sample-test, and got 100% correctness, 0% performance, 55% total score. Always interesting to see a one-line solution.

Comment: `Shortest answer in Python` Use of `sorted()` is unhelpful. Not sure if the set isn't created for each and every `x`.

Answer (score 2):

A solution in `kotlin` using set.

**Space complexity: O(N)

Time complexity: O(N)**

```
fun solutionUsingSet(A: IntArray): Int {
    val set = HashSet<Int>()
    A.forEach {
        if (it > 0) {
            set.add(it)
        }
    }
    // If input array has no positive numbers
    if (set.isEmpty()) {
        return 1
    }
    for (i in 1 until A.size + 1) {
        if (!set.contains(i)) {
            return i
        }
    }
    // If input array has all numbers from 1 to N occurring once
    return A.size + 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP, passes 100%

```php
function solution ($A) {

    sort ($A);
    $smol = 1;
  
    foreach ($A as $a) {
        if ($a > 0) {
            if ($smol === $a) {
                $smol++;
            } else {
                if (($a + 1) < $smol) {
                  $smol = ($a + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $smol;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
A = [-1, -3]
A = [1, 4, -4, -2, 4, 7, 9]

def solution(A):
    A.sort()
    A = list(set(A))
    A = list(filter(lambda x: x > 0, A))

    if len(A) == 0:
        return 1

    x = min(A)
    if(max(A) <= 0 or x > 1):
        return 1

    # print(A)
    for i in range(len(A)):
        increment = 1 if i+1 < len(A) else 0
        payload = A[i+increment]
        #print(payload, x)
        if payload - x == 1:
            x = payload
        else:
            return x + 1
     print(solution(A))
```

[image]

Comment: This is not 100% :)

Answer (score 2):

C# version

```
class Solution {
public int solution(int[] A) {
    var res=1;
    Array.Sort(A);
    for(int i=0; i< A.Length; i++)
    {
        if(res<A[i])
        {
            break;
        }

        res= (A[i]>0?A[i]:0) + 1;
    }
    return res;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

this got 100% for C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;            
public static int solution(int[] A)
        {
            List<int> lst = A.Select(r => r).Where(r => r > 0).OrderBy(r => r).Distinct().ToList();

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", lst));
            
            if (lst.Count == 0)
                return 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
            {
                if (lst[i] != i + 1)
                    return i + 1;
            }
            return lst.Count + 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

input : `A: IntArray`

```
// Sort A to find the biggest number in the last position on the list
A.sort()
// create `indexed for loop` from `1` to the biggest number in the last position on the list
for (int i = 1; i < A[A.length]; i++) {
    // check for current index (positive number)  not found in the list
    if ((i in A).not()) println("Answe : $i")
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Added some comments to describe

Answer (score 2):

The task asks for the minimal non-existing in the array A integer, which is greater than 0.

I think this is the right solution:

1. get the A into a set, to minimize the size by eliminate duplicates and getting the search in the set availability with Set.contains() method.
2. Check the max value in the set. if it is smaller than 0, then return 1 (smallest integer, which is not contained in the set and larger than 0)
3. If the max value is greater than 0, stream through the integers from 1 to max value and check if any of them is missing from the set, then return it.

Here is the solution:

```
public static int solution(int[] A) {
    Set<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<>();
    Arrays.stream(A).forEach(mySet::add);
    int maxVal = Collections.max(mySet);
    return maxVal <=0 ? 1 :
           IntStream.range(1, maxVal).filter(i -> !mySet.contains(i)).findFirst().orElse(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, this passed 100% correctness and performance

```
function solution($A){ 
  $min = 1;
  sort($A); 
  for($i = 0 ; $i < count($A); $i++){
    if($A[$i] == $min){
        $min++;
    }
  }
  return $min; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 Answer

```
func getSmallestPositive(array: [Int]) -> Int {

    let positive = Array(Set(array))
    let positiveArray = positive.filter({$0 > 0}).sorted()
    var initialNumber = 1
    for number in 0..<positiveArray.count {
        let item = positiveArray[number]
        if item > initialNumber {
            return initialNumber
        }
        initialNumber = item + 1
    }
    return initialNumber
}
```

Usage

```
    var array = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2]
    let numbeFinal = getNumber(array: array)
    print(numbeFinal)
```

Answer (score 2):

This my solution in R

```
Solution <- function(A){
  if(max(A) < 1){
    return(1)
  }
  B = 1:max(A)
  if(length(B[!B %in% A])==0){
    return(max(A)+1)
  }
  else {
    return(min(B[!B %in% A]))
  }
}
```

Evaluate the function in sample vectors

```
C = c(1,3,6,4,1,2)
D = c(1,2,3)
E = c(-1,-3)
G = c(-1,-3,9)

Solution(C)
Solution(D)
Solution(E)
Solution(G)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done it using Linq. Pure C# . Working fine for below inputs :

```
//int[] abc = { 1,5,3,6,2,1}; // working
//int[] abc = { 1,2,3}; -- working
//int[] abc = { -1, -2, -3 }; -- working
//int[] abc = { 10000, 99999, 12121 }; -- working

        //find the smallest positive missing no.

    Array.Sort(abc);
    int[] a = abc.Distinct().ToArray();
    int output = 0;

    var minvalue = a[0];
    var maxValue = a[a.Length - 1];

    for (int index = minvalue; index < maxValue; index++)
    {
        if (!a.Contains(index))
        {
            output = index;
            break;
        }
    }           

    if (output == 0)
    {
        if (maxValue < 1)
        {
            output = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            output = maxValue + 1;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(" Output :" + output);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift**

```
public func solution(_ A : inout [Int]) -> Int {
    // write your code in Swift 4.2.1 (Linux)

 var smallestValue = 1
 if A.count == 0 {
     return smallestValue
 }
 A.sort()
 if (A[0] > 1) || (A[A.count - 1] <= 0) {
    return smallestValue
 }
 for index in 0..<A.count {
     if A[index] == smallestValue {
         smallestValue = smallestValue + 1
     }
 }
 return smallestValue
}
```

Comment: Say you have a sorted input that is [1....10000] and only 2 is missing in it. Wouldn't it unnecessarily go through all the items? You should consider breaking the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby 2.2 solution. [Total score](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingJNBQHX-98C/) 77% due to somewhat weak performance.

```
def solution(a)
  positive_sorted = a.uniq.sort.select {|i| i > 0 }
  return 1 if (positive_sorted.empty? || positive_sorted.first > 1)

  positive_sorted.each do |i|
    res = i + 1
    next if positive_sorted.include?(res)
    return res
  end
end
```

Comment: Is this because of the performance of Ruby?

Comment: Definatelly, why performance is low when you sort an array of size 1*10^6

Answer (score 2):

> This code has been written in C
>
> The existing was in C++ and Java

```
function solution(A) {
    // only positive values, sorted
    int i,j,small,large,value,temp,skip=0;
    int arr[N];
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        value = A[i];
        for(j=i;j<N;j++)
        {
            if(value > A[j])
            {
                temp = value;
                value = A[j];
                A[j] = temp;
            }            
        }
        
        arr[i] = value;
    }
    small = arr[0];
    large = arr[N-1];
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == arr[i+1])
        {            
            for(j=i;j<(N);j++)
            {
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];
            }
            skip++;                         
        }
        
    }
    if(large < 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    for(i=0;i<(N);i++)
    {        
        if(arr[i] != (small+i))
        {
            return (arr[i-1]+1);
        }
        else if(arr[i] == large)
        {
            return (large+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my 100% correct solution with swift 4 using `Set` and avoiding the use of `sorted()`.

```
     let setOfIntegers = Set<Int>(A)
        var max = 0
        for integer in stride(from: 1, to: A.count + 1, by: 1) {
            max = integer > max ? integer : max
            if (!setOfIntegers.contains(integer)) {
                return integer
            }
        }
        
        return  max + 1
```

Comment: what's the purpose of the below line?
max = integer > max ? integer : max.
we can use it simply like max = integer

Comment: @RajaSaad in this case, since we're dealing with an unordered set, we only want `max` to be set to `integer` if `integer` is actually larger than `max`. The result of `max` can then be used to return the smallest positive integer that does not occur in the set where we return `max + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it works for me

```
import java.util.*;
    class Solution {
        public static int solution(int[] A) {
            // write your code in Java SE 8
            int m = Arrays.stream(A).max().getAsInt(); //Storing maximum value 
            if (m < 1) // In case all values in our array are negative 
            { 
                return 1; 
            } 
            if (A.length == 1) { 

                //If it contains only one element 
                if (A[0] == 1) { 
                    return 2; 
                } else { 
                    return 1; 
                } 
            } 
            int min = A[0];
            int max= A[0];
            int sm = 1;

            HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

            for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++){
                set.add(A[i]);

                if(A[i]<min){
                    min = A[i];
                }
                if(A[i]>max){
                    max = A[i];
                }
            }

            if(min <= 0){
                min = 1;
            }

            if(max <= 0){
                max = 1;
            }

            boolean fnd = false;
            for(int i=min;i<=max;i++){
                if(i>0 && !set.contains(i)){
                    sm = i;
                    fnd = true;
                    break;
                }
                else continue;

            }
            if(fnd)
                return sm; 
            else return max +1;
        }

              public static void main(String args[]){

               Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("enter number of elements");

            int n=s.nextInt();

            int arr[]=new int[n];

            System.out.println("enter elements");

            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){//for reading array
                arr[i]=s.nextInt();

            }

        int array[] = arr;

        // Calling getMax() method for getting max value
        int max = solution(array);
        System.out.println("Maximum Value is: "+max);

      }
    }
```

Comment: This is practically a code-only answer. Please improve it with some explanation. Why and how does this help?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way using while loop:

```
fun solution(A: IntArray): Int {
    var value = 1
    var find = false
    while(value < A.size) {
        val iterator = A.iterator()
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            if (value == iterator.nextInt()) {
                find = true
                value++
            }
        }
        if (!find) {
            break
        } else {
            find = false
        }
    }
    return value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is might help you, it should work fine!

```
public static int sol(int[] A)
{
    boolean flag =false;
    for(int i=1; i<=1000000;i++ ) {
        for(int j=0;j<A.length;j++) {
            if(A[j]==i) {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }else {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        if(flag) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: This is practically a code-only answer. Please improve it with some explanation of how and why it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to get this done !!

```
public int  findNearestPositive(int array[])
{
    boolean isNegative=false;
    int number=0;
    int value=0;

    if(array[0]<=0 && array[array.length-1]<0)
    {
    return 1;


    }

    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
    value=i+1;
    isNegative=false;

    for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++)
    {
    if(value==array[j])
    {
    isNegative=true;

    }

    }

    if(isNegative!=true)
    {
    if(number==0){

    number=value;
    }else if(value<number){
    number=value;
    }

    }               

    }


    if(number==0)
    {

    number=value+1;
    }

    return number;

}
```

Comment: Quite a lot of lines for a `Simple way`.

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach with Java.  The time complexity of this answer is 2*O(N) because I iterate through Array A twice.

```java
import java.util.HashMap;

public static final Integer solution(int[] A) {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(A.length); //O(n) space

    for (int i : A) {
        if (!map.containsKey(i)) {
            map.put(i, i);
        }
    }

    int minorPositive = 100000;
    for (int i : A) {
        if (!map.containsKey(i + 1)) {
            if (i < minorPositive) {
                minorPositive = i + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (minorPositive < 0){
        minorPositive = 1;
    }
    return minorPositive;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen a C# solution that uses Linq yet... the following is the simplest way (I think) to get 100% pass on this test:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) => Enumerable.Range(1, 100001).Except(A).Min();
}
```

However, I should note that whilst the above is simple, and will get 100% pass on the test, it's not the most efficient. For a more efficient Linq solution, something like the following will work better:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static int solution(int[] A)
{
    var set = new HashSet<int>(A);

    return Enumerable.Range(1, A.Length + 1).First(i => !set.Contains(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution in JavaScript**

```
function solution(A) {
    let smallestInt = 1;

    function existsInArray(val) {
        return A.find((a) => a === val);
    }

    for (let index = smallestInt; index < 1000000; index++) {
        if (existsInArray(index) && !existsInArray(index + 1) &&
            existsInArray(smallestInt)) {
            smallestInt = index + 1
        }
    }
    return smallestInt;
}
```

Comment: Performance-wise, not a great solution (Detected time complexity:
O(N**2) )

Answer (score 1):

Not the best C++ but it got 100% score https://app.codility.com/demo/results/demoCNNMBE-B5W/

```
// you can use includes, for example:
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// cout << "this is a debug message" << endl;

template <class T>
bool allneg(const T start, const T end) {
    T it;
    for (it = start; it != end; it++) {
        if (*it >= 0) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    if(A.empty()) throw std::invalid_argument("unexpected empty vector");

    std::sort(A.begin(),A.end());
    /*
    for(size_t i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << A[i] << ", ";
    }*/
    if(allneg(A.begin(),A.end())){
        return 1;
    }
    int v = 1;
    auto it = A.begin();
    while(it!=A.end()){
        if(std::binary_search(it,A.end(),v)){
            v++;
        } else {
            return v;
        }
        it++;
    }
    return v;
}
```

Based on [Fastest way to find smallest missing integer from list of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53466817) and slightly faster than the above https://app.codility.com/demo/results/demoCJ7MDF-CDD/

```
int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    // write your code in C++14 (g++ 6.2.0)
    std::vector<bool> negative(1000000,false);
    std::vector<bool> non_negative(1000000+1,false);
    bool contain_negative = false;
    bool contain_non_negative = false;
    for(int a : A){
        if(a<0) {
            negative[-a] = true;
            contain_negative = true;
        } else {
            non_negative[a] = true;
            contain_non_negative = true;
        }
    }
    int result = 1;
    if(contain_negative && !contain_non_negative){
        return result;
    } else {
        for(size_t i = 1; i < non_negative.size(); i++){
            if(!non_negative[i]){
                result = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for JavaScript

```js
let arr = [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2];
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
let arr2 = [-1, -3];

function solution(A) {
    let smallestInteger = 1;

    A.forEach(function (val) {
        if (A.includes(smallestInteger)) {
            if (val > 0) smallestInteger++;
        }
    });

    return smallestInteger;
}

console.log(solution(arr));
console.log(solution(arr1));
console.log(solution(arr2));
```

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent and simplest code in Python 3.6

```
def solution(A):
    ab = set(range(1,abs(max(A))+2)).difference(set(A))
    return min(ab)
```

**Passed all test cases, Correctness test cases, and Performance test cases**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm

for element element is array which is in range [1, N] and not in its correct place, swap this element with element of its correct place.
Which ever index don’t match with its element is the answer.

```
class Solution {
public int firstMissingPositive(int[] nums) {
    int n = nums.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < n;) {
        if(nums[i] >= 1 && nums[i] <= n && nums[i] != nums[nums[i]-1]) {
            swap(nums,nums[i]-1,i);
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(nums[i] != i+1) return i+1;
    }
    return n+1;
}

private void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort way with JS

```
function solution(A) {
  let result = 1;
  A.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if (A[i] === result) {
      result++;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Example test cases: Passed 3 out of 3
 * Correctness test cases: Passed 5 out of 5
 * Performance test cases: Passed 4 out of 4
 */
public int solution(int[] A) {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (int n : A) {
        if (n > 0) {
            set.add(n);
        }
    }
    int smallest = 1;
    for (int ignored : set) {
        if (!set.contains(smallest)) {
            return smallest;
        }
        smallest = smallest + 1;
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

Comment: This assumes that `set` is sorted, which isn't necessarily the case. For example, if `set = { 1, 6, 4, 2, 3 1 }`, this will return `7` instead of `5`.

Comment: @cutsoy Actually not. Set shouldn't be sorted because the contains method doesn't depend on sorting. This method returns 5. Can you please provide an input that breaks the result? I'd glad to check it.

Comment: Given the input I mentioned, at iter. 0, `smallest = 1` (which is in the set). At iter. 1, `smallest = 6 + 1`, which is not in the set and it returns `6 + 1`. I think it would work if it's `for (int n = 0; n < set.size(); n += 1)` instead of `for (int n : set)`.

Comment: I got you. You mean that iterating over a set may be out of order in which case there will be an error. You are right, in some cases might be an error! Coincidentally, although HashSet does not guarantee order, an iterator returns numbers in ascending order so this solution works for Codility tests. http://prntscr.com/PlZ9jkIauXWB

Comment: Fixed with `smallest = smallest + 1;`
https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingWU3WTE-K4R/
Detected time complexity: O(N) or O(N * log(N)).
Task Score, Correctness, Performance: 100%
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin (1.6.0 and higher) with Total score at 100%

```
fun solution(A: IntArray): Int {
   var min = 1
   val b = A.sortedArray()
   for (element in b) {
     if ((element - 1) == min) min++
   }
   return min
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5.0**

```
public func solution(_ A : inout [Int]) -> Int {
   
    var missing: [Int: Bool] = [:]
    var found: [Int:Bool] = [:]
    var greatestNum = 0
   
    for i in 0...A.count-1 {
        let num = A[i]
        if num > 1 {
            missing.removeValue(forKey: num)
            found[num] = true
            if num-1 > 1 {
                if found[num-1] == nil {
                    missing[num-1] = true
                }
            }
            
            if num > greatestNum {
                greatestNum = num
            }
        }
    }
    
    return missing.first?.key ?? greatestNum+1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest PHP solution

```php
function solution($A) {
    // write your code in PHP7.0
    $lastNum = 1;
    
    while(in_array($lastNum, $A)) {
        $lastNum++;
    }
    
    return $lastNum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def solution(A):
    A = sorted(filter(lambda x: x >= 0, A))
    if A is []:
        return 1
    for i in range(1, 100000):
        if i not in A:
            return i
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Comment: @EduardoBaitello all the answers are here code ONLY :D

Comment: @ChakladerAsfakArefe thanks for your thoughts. I recommend the following reads: [What comment should I add to code-only answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300837/7641078) and [Low quality posts and code only answers.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345719/low-quality-posts-and-code-only-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Swift with `.reduce()`

```swift
public func solution(_ A : inout [Int]) -> Int {
    return A.filter { $0 > 0 }.sorted().reduce(1) { $0 < $1 ? $0 : $1 + 1}
}
```

Comment: Glad to see `Swift` is here too.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with Swift and got 100%.

```swift
public func solution(_ A : inout [Int]) -> Int {
    // write your code in Swift 4.2.1 (Linux)
    if A.count == 0 {
        return 1
    }
    A = A.sorted()
    if A[A.count - 1] <= 0 {
        return 1
    }
    
    var temp = 1
    
    for numb in A {
        
        if numb > 0 {
            
            if numb == temp {
                temp += 1
            }else if numb != (temp - 1) {
                return temp
            }
        }
    }
    
    return temp
}
```

Comment: Performance will degrade in case of large arrays because of A = A.sorted(). The way to go is rather sacrifise memory than CPU time

Comment: @greybeard you keep editing swift code even today, and 2 days ago he told me he does not know swift.

Answer (score 0):

My solution on Ruby

```rb
def solution(a)
  p = {}
  b = 1
  a.each do |n|
    p[n] = n
    b = n if n > b
  end

  nb = b
  (b-1).downto(1) do |n|
    unless p[n]
      nb = n
      break
    end
  end  
  (nb == b) ? b+1 : nb
end

puts solution([1,3,5,4,1,2,6])
puts solution([1,3,6,4,1,2,5])
puts solution([1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 0):

My Java solution got 100%. I feel this is simple and the complexity is O(n).

```java
public int solution(int[] A) {
    Integer s = 1;
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i : A) {
        if (i>0) {
            list.add(i);
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(list);

    for (int i : list) {
        if (s < i) {
            return s;
        }
        s = i + 1;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Let me know if we can improve this more.

Comment: With `Collections.sort(list)` in there, I don't think this is O(n) anymore, but rather O(n * log(n)).

Answer (score 0):

In PHP I can achieve it from a few lines of code.

```
function solution($A) {
  for($i=1; in_array($i,$A); $i++);
  return $i;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# solution:

```
    public int solution(int[] A)
    {
        int result = 1;

        // write your code in Java SE 8
        foreach(int num in A)
        {
            if (num == result)
               result++;

            while (A.Contains(result))
                result++;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ Answer to this question.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
  
// One function works for all data types.  This would work
// even for user defined types if operator '>' is overloaded
template <typename T> T myMax(T x, T y)
{
    return (x > y) ? x : y;
}

int removeDuplicates(vector<int> &arr, int n)
{
    // Return, if array is empty or contains a single
    // element
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return n;
 
    int temp[n];
 
    // Start traversing elements
    int j = 0;
    // If current element is not equal to next element
    // then store that current element
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        if (arr[i] != arr[i + 1])
            temp[j++] = arr[i];
 
    // Store the last element as whether it is unique or
    // repeated, it hasn't stored previously
    temp[j++] = arr[n - 1];
 
    // Modify original array
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
        arr[i] = temp[i];
 
    return j;
}
 
int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    // write your code in C++14 (g++ 6.2.0)0
    std::vector<int> vect2;
     int temp= 1;
        // if(A.size() == 0)
        // {
        //     return 0;
        // }
        {

         sort(A.begin(), A.end());
         int n = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);
         n = removeDuplicates(A, n);
         
        
            for(int i=0; i<A.size(); i++)
            {
                if(A[i]!= i+1)
                {
              
                    temp = i+1;
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    temp = i+2;
                }
                
                //  return i+1;
            }
            return temp;
        }
}

int main()
{
   

    std::vector<int> vect;
    vect.push_back(1);
    vect.push_back(2);
    vect.push_back(3);

    cout<<solution(vect);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS,

```
function solution(A) {
    
  let arr = [...new Set(A)].sort();
  let fullArr = [];
  let smallest = 1;
  for(let i=1; i<= arr.length ; i++){
      fullArr.push(i);
  }
  
  let difference = fullArr.filter(x => !arr.includes(x));
  if(difference.length > 0)
       smallest = difference[0];
  else {
      smallest = arr[arr.length-1];
      smallest++
  }
  
  return smallest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a nice solution in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def solution(A):    
    max_number=max(A)

    if max_number<0:
        return 1

    set_A=set(A)
    set_B=set(range(1,max_number+1))
    set_D=set_B-set_A

    if len(set_D)==0:
        return max_number+1
    else:
        return min(set_D)




print(solution([1,3,6,4,1,2])) #should print 5
print(solution([1,2,3])) #should print 4 
print(solution([-1,-3])) #should print 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution in C++ (100% score) using **HashSet**.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    // Implement your solution here
    int length = A.size();
    unordered_set<int> hash;
    for(int x : A){
        if(x > 0)
            hash.insert(x);
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= length + 1; i++){
        if(hash.find(i) == hash.end())
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the c# Solution for this Problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
                    Array.Sort(A);
            var last = A.Last();
            var first = A.First();
            var listA = A.ToList();
            var res = 1;
            for (int i = first; i <= last + 1; i++)
            {
                if (!listA.Any(x => x == i) && i > 0)
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return res;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

100% result solution in C++ :

```
int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    if(A.empty())
    {
        return 1;
    }
    sort(A.begin(), A.end());
    bool flagForOne = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
    {
        if(A[i] == 1)
        {
            flagForOne = true;
        }
    }
    if(flagForOne == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < A.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        if((A[i] > 0) && (A[i+1] - A[i]) > 1))
        {
            return (A[i] + 1);
        }
    }
    return A[A.size() - 1] + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is logic written in python to start searching for 1 in array and then go on by adding 1 integer into that. If at any stage value is not found then break the loop and return that value.

{
def solution(A):
b= 1
for i in A:
if b not in A:
break
else:
b=b+1
return b
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Linear complexity **O(2N)** which simplifies to **O(N)**. I used two sequentials loops, **no nested loops**. Performance 100%, Correctness 100% according to codility: https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingR7Y4E4-REP/. *It shows 1 min completion time because I forgot to set length of (1000000 + 1) so I re-ran test again*

```java
// you can also use imports, for example:
import java.util.Arrays;

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// System.out.println("this is a debug message");

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] array) {
        boolean[] nums = new boolean[1000000 + 1];// for indexing purpose.

        Arrays.stream(array).forEach(i -> {
            if(i > 0) {
                nums[i] = true;
            }
        });

        if(!nums[1])
            return 1;

        for(int i = 2; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if(!nums[i])
                return i;
        }

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use `array.length` as a limit for the size of `nums.` You could keep a max of the `i`s in the `forEach` as an upper limit for the `for`. Why special case `nums[1]`? The last `return` (reached for out-of-spec input only) returns a perfectly valid value: this looks odd. You left in irrelevant comments, but forgot to document (`Solution`and) `solution()`.

Comment: @greybeard I dont know which kind of quick sort swift is using but you got very lucky ending up in codility time limits for sorting algorithm + linear search, in java's quick sort implementation it goes beyond time limitation of mark "100%" for quick sort

Comment: @greybeard observe the best solution by this author: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73105961/11704057 No sort, no cpu utilization, no memory utilization

Comment: I did not present any solution. I don't code in Swift. I don't disclose information to *competitive coding* sites - the only way I'd possibly get results was entering anonymously - up to now, I never saw a site allowing that, nor did I look for one. I'm not with mind reading over the internet. Following your hyperlink to [rohit verma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73105961/11704057) this question, I find another piece of undocumented code, never mentioning it modifies its input (in the code, and not spelling it out in the post).

Comment: @greybeard it is your problem if you did not understand code, dont write false comments if did not see the logic

Comment: @greybeard "You could use array.length as a limit for the size of nums."

Comment: @greybeard I dont belive that you are able to solve [ 3, 6, -2, 3, 2, 1 ] without sorting first, you can make as many false statements as you wish, continue wasting your time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248319/discussion-between-m22-and-greybeard).

Answer (score -2):

This works very well for Java. It uses bitwise exclusive OR and assignment operator

```java
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8
        int sol = 0;
        for(int val:A){
            sol ^= val;
        }
        return sol;
    }
}
```

Comment: does not work with negative numbers or with (even) duplicates of numbers.

Comment: @tucuxi at least appreciates his effort as a new member of the forum.