# Return the lowest positive integer value not contained in an int[] array, optimized for performance

Tags: c#, arrays, performance

I was doing an assessment online to return the lowest positive value of an int not in the array.

I used this code:

```
class Solution
{
    public static int solution(int[] A)
    {
        int hold = 1;

        while (A.Contains(hold))
        {
            hold++;
        }

        return hold;
    }
}
```

It works and received 100% for correctness however got 25% for efficiency. How can I make this more efficient? The website states that the testing can be of an array up to 100,000 values. My coding skills outside of WinForms are lacking and I would appreciate any help in order to make my code more efficient.

An example test would be `[1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2]`, and it would return `5`.

Comment: Well, you could make that O(n) by iterating the array only once.

Comment: @Fildor how would i do that?

Comment: Is the array pre-sorted?

Comment: @Charlieface no, an example test would be [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2] and it would return 5

Comment: Related language-agnostic question: [Find the smallest positive integer that does not occur in a given sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51719848/find-the-smallest-positive-integer-that-does-not-occur-in-a-given-sequence).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias not sure how i didnt see that - exact same website i was using. thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest change would be to turn the array into a `HashSet<int>`. This reduces the lookup time `A.Contains(hold)` from O(n) to essentially O(1):

```
    public static int solution(int[] A)
    {
        var hashSet = new HashSet<int>(A);
        int hold = 1;

        while (hashSet.Contains(hold))
        {
            hold++;
        }

        return hold;
    }
```

Comment: Optimization for memory: add only positive numbers in the `hashSet`. Non-positive numbers can be safely ignored.

Answer (score 2):

This code tests whether a continuous positive integer exists, so you can sort the array first, then find out the discontinuous position.

```
public static int solution(int[] A)
{
    Array.Sort(A);

    var j = Array.IndexOf(A, 1);
    if (j < 0)
        return 1;

    int k = 1;
    for (int i = j + 1; i < A.Length; i++)
    {
        if (A[i] - k > 1)
            break;
        k = A[i];
    }
    return k + 1;
}
```

Comment: using the test data [1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2], this should return 5, however it returns 1

Comment: A minor flaw of this solution is that it modifies its argument, which is generally undesirable.

Comment: tested this on the website, 60% correctness (failed 3 tests - i wonder if that's related to the negative number/zero bug @TheodorZoulias noticed), and 50% on performance. performance is better than my original attempt but not as fast/efficient as the accepted solution (100% on both)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thank you for pointing out the bug. Update again, now I will find the first 1 first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a LINQ approach. It's unlikely to be as fast as the solutions in the other answers. It might be a bit cuter though:

```
public static int GetLowestPositiveNumberNotContained(int[] array)
{
    return array
        .Where(n => n > 0)
        .Distinct()
        .Order()
        .Append(-1)
        .Zip(Enumerable.Range(1, Array.MaxLength + 1))
        .First(e => e.First != e.Second)
        .Second;
}
```

Explanation:

1. We filter out the non-positive numbers in the array.
2. We filter out the duplicates.
3. We sort the filtered query (unique positive numbers in the array).
4. We append a negative number (sentinel) at the end, so that [we don't fall into the Mediterranean sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant_in_Cairo).
5. We create pairs by zipping the query (sorted unique positive numbers), with an incremental sequence of numbers that starts from `1`.
6. We find the first pair having non-equal members.
7. The second member of this pair is the number that we are searching for. It's the lowest positive number not contained in the array.

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ARnfdD).