# Smallest positive integer that does not occur in an array

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am attempting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51719848/find-the-smallest-positive-integer-that-does-not-occur-in-a-given-sequence) using javascript. When I run my implementation on the website I get 11%, which asides from poor runtime states that I fail four hidden tests.

I cannot understand how my implementation is failing. I understand its not a great implementation and there are cleaner working answers in the linked question, but I am still curious *what false logic I am using*.

```js
  A = A.filter(a => a > 0).sort()

  if (A.length === 0) {
    return 1
  }
  
  if (A.length === 1) {
    return A[0] + 1
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    let curr = A[i]
    let next = A[i + 1]

    if (curr !== next && (curr + 1) !== next) {
      return curr + 1
    }
  }
```

My logic is that since I am traversing a sorted array of positive integers from lowest to highest, if the current element + 1 doesn't equal the following element (i.e. [5,7] would be 5 + 1 != 7), there is a gap, which is the missing integer.

And if the loop gets all the way to the end, the last `if` statement still triggers since next is `undefined`, which would return the max value + 1.

Comment: dont know if this is it sort() does weird things with negative numbers in it . try something like `[-1,4,2,-3].sort()`  and `[-1,4,2,-3].sort((a,b) => a-b)` to see what i meant

Comment: Unless you are using [Typed Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray), `sort()` will give you lexicographic order, not numeric order, i.e. [1,11,2] instead of [1,2,11]

Comment: @cmgchess `.sort()` is called upon an array without negative numbers

Comment: Your function fails to return the expected result (`1`) for simple inputs such as `[2,3]` or `[2]`.

Comment: Also, as Moritz mentioned: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly

Comment: @Bergi ah missed it filters

Comment: Thank you both for providing failing examples! ChatGPT failed to provide me a _single_ one.. The logical fallacies are clear as day now

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sorting the array, just look for the max of the array and use that within your function. Note that instead of working on arrays, you could use sets. The set `.has` method is faster than `include` method.

```js
function  smallest_positive(ar){
    let set = new Set(ar)
    let mx = Math.max(...set);
    for(let i = 1; i < mx; i++) 
        if(!set.has(i)) return i;
    return mx < 1 ? 1: mx + 1;
}; 

console.log(smallest_positive([-1,4,2,-3]))
console.log(smallest_positive([1, 2, 3]))
console.log(smallest_positive([5,7]))
console.log(smallest_positive([1, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2]))
```

Comment: Repeatedly using `.includes()` is way worse than sorting the array

Comment: @Bergi just fixed and used `.has`. That should be better

Comment: The complexity of this solution is `O(M)`, where `M = max(arr)`. The question states an expected complexity of `O(N)`.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Not really. This is a short circuited function. Note that in whatever case you have, the order for this way less than N. I am not iterating through all numbers to M. I am just using M as the upper bound. Eg, let your array be `[1000, -1]`, max is 1000. but i will only iterate once since 1 is not in the array and short circuit the function thus returning 1. If you had `[-1,-2,-3,-4,-5]` max is `-1` and the for loop is completely ignored since `i>max` So we just return 1.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur  In a worst case scenario where we have `[..., -5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...n]` note that i will iterate from 1 to n and then output n+1. Only iterating a subset of the array. Which is way better that iterating through all the elements of the vector.

Comment: @Onyambu can't you use `N` as the upper bound then?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur yes. But I would prefer the `N = Set.length` which is considerably smaller than `N = array.length` But still would work the same. Bothfunctions will be short circuited at the same value. So